# How can I use a new Perl module without install permissions?

Tags: perl, cpan

Here is my situation: I know almost nothing about Perl, but it is the only language available on a porting machine. I only have permissions to write in my local work area and not the Perl install location. I need to use the [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager) Perl module from CPAN.

How do I use this `Parallel::ForkManager` without doing a central install? Is there an environment variable that I can set so it is located?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install CPAN modules locally without root access (DynaLoader.pm line 229 error)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102850/how-can-i-install-cpan-modules-locally-without-root-access-dynaloader-pm-line-2)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [perlfaq8:  How do I keep my own module/library directory?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_keep_my_own):

When you build modules, tell Perl where to install the modules.

For C-based distributions, use the INSTALL_BASE option
when generating Makefiles:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl
```

You can set this in your CPAN.pm configuration so modules automatically install
in your private library directory when you use the CPAN.pm shell:

```
% cpan
cpan> o conf makepl_arg INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl
cpan> o conf commit
```

For C-based distributions, use the --install_base option:

```
perl Build.PL --install_base /mydir/perl
```

You can configure CPAN.pm to automatically use this option too:

```
% cpan
cpan> o conf mbuild_arg --install_base /mydir/perl
cpan> o conf commit
```

INSTALL_BASE tells these tools to put your modules into
F.  See L for details on how to run your newly
installed moudles.

There is one caveat with INSTALL_BASE, though, since it acts
differently than the PREFIX and LIB settings that older versions of
ExtUtils::MakeMaker advocated. INSTALL_BASE does not support
installing modules for multiple versions of Perl or different
architectures under the same directory. You should consider if you
really want that , and if you do, use the older PREFIX and LIB
settings. See the ExtUtils::Makemaker documentation for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Download package form CPAN to a folder:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SZ/SZABGAB/Parallel-ForkManager-1.06.tar.gz
gunzip Parallel-ForkManager-1.06.tar.gz
tar -xvf Parallel-ForkManager-1.06.tar
```

before this create a folder in home to store your local modules, now go into downloaded folder and run follwing cmmands:

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/username/myModules
make
make test
make install
```

get the path to ForkManager from the installed folder,/home/username/myModules
and locate Parallel folder and get the full path to this.

Now in your perl file put these at the beggining

```
use lib '/home/username/myModules/bin.../Parallel';
use parallel::ForkManager;
```

--That should do it.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this post](http://blog.plover.com/prog/lib.html) from Mark Dominus

Excerpt:

> - Set PREFIX=X when building the Makefile
> - Set INSTALLDIRS=vendor and VENDORPREFIX=X when building the Makefile
>
>   - Or maybe instead of VENDORPREFIX you need to set INSTALLVENDORLIB or something
>   - Or maybe instead of setting them while building the Makefile you need to set them while running the make install target
> - Set LIB=X/lib when building the Makefile
> - Use PAR
> - Use local::lib

Mark also gives another solution in his blog which takes a bit more space to desribe but boils down to running make and make test but not make install and then using the stuff in blib/.

Comment: There's no reason to mess with vendor stuff.  You should leave INSTALLDIRS as it is, "site" is correct for locally installed modules.  And use INSTALL_BASE, not PREFIX/LIB.

Answer (score 4):

There's the PERL5LIB environment variable, and `-I` on the command line when it comes to using the module.  There are mechanisms for telling CPAN and CPANPLUS.

There is information in question 5 of the CPAN manual (perldoc CPAN, or look at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) itself).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-I` (capital i) command-line switch followed by the directory where you'll place the module; or try the "use lib" directive followed by the directory.

```
-Idirectory
        may be used in conjunction with -P to tell the C preprocessor where to look for include files. By default /usr/include and /usr/lib/perl are searched.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use lib 'directory';
use Parallel::ForkManager;
```

Comment: This is too minimalistic. As a beginner, I tried using the `module-starter` from https://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod. I created a module Test-Module and for the love of everything that's holy I cannot use this module using this syntax, and I would expect it to be `use lib 'Test-Module'; use Test::Module;`

Answer (score 2):

[Yes Even You Can Use CPAN](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl Makefile.PL LIB=/my/perl_modules/lib/
make
make install
PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/my/perl_modules/lib/
perl myperlcode.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

use `cpanm -l $DIR_NAME` option.

Answer (score 1):

[`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl) lets you use a local perl and installs it's packages to a local directory.

```
\curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash

perlbrew init  # put this in .bash_profile etc

perlbrew install 5.27.11

perlbrew switch 5.27.11
```

See also https://opensource.com/article/18/7/perlbrew.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using cpanminus, a suggested on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-to-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user)