# How to send commands to windows command prompt using a PERL script

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to send some commands to windows command prompt using 'PERL' script.
the command is:
putty.exe -ssh -2 -l username -pw password "ip address"
this command will open an SSH session (console)to the mentioned ip address (server) for me.
after getting the new console, I want to pass commands to and perform operations in the new console.How can I do that as well?

Please help

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848725/how-can-i-ssh-inside-a-perl-script You will probably want to use the Perl Expect module and then the "interact" command that lets you interact with whatever you have spawned.

Comment: That should be an answer, imho. There is really not a lot more to say.

Comment: reposted elsewhere [http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1078146]

Comment: hello doctor, perl monk link is 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'system' or 'exec' command.

system:

```
@args = ("command", "arg1", "arg2");
system(@args) == 0
    or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

exec:

```
exec '/bin/echo', 'Your arguments are: ', @ARGV;
exec "sort $outfile | uniq";
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html

Please notice the difference between them.