# SSH connection timeout in Net::SSH::Perl

Tags: perl, ssh, timeout

I'm using Net::SSH::Perl to connect to remote server and execute commands. The problem is that it doesn't get timed out even if the remote server doesn't respond for a long time. I don't find any timeout option in Net::SSH::Perl.

Any help to achieve timeout is appreciated.

Note: I don't have the rights to modify Net/SSH/Perl.pm

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ConnectTimeout` option.

Sample:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my %params = ( protocol => "2,1",
                identity_files => ["/home/user/.ssh/test_id_dsa"],
                options => [    "BatchMode yes",
                                "ConnectTimeout 3",
                                "StrictHostKeyChecking no"],
                debug => 'true'
);
```

Also see: [Net::SSH::Perl ConnectTimeout (ssh -o option)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=566455)

Comment: As per the link given, the user is trying the ConnectTimeout option in Net::SSH::Perl and it's not working. So, the temporary solution is to add setsockopt in Perl.pm. As I don't have the rights to modify Perl.pm, I can't implement it. Anyway, is the ConnectTimeout option working for you?

Comment: I didn't test it so I don't know whether this works on my machine or not. I use Net::OpenSSH, you can try using that. Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2851593/257635

Comment: Even if this option had been implemented in Net::SSH::Perl, it wouldn't have helped the author. It defines a ConnectTimeout, e.g. the timeout for establishing a connection, and what the author wants is actually ServerAliveInterval, which is not implemented in Net::SSH::Perl also.

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong and the author really needs to detect a connection timeout, not the keep-alive timeout. In such case ConnectTimeout would have helped of course (if Net::SSH::Perl supported it, but it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

As I see from your `%params`, you use the DSA key to authenticate on the remote server. Do you *really* need to use the native Perl SSH implementation that `Net::SSH::Perl` provides? It is useful in some cases where you cannot just wrap the regular `ssh` call (e.g. if you need to provide a clear-text password for connecting to the server), but it lacks so many useful SSH options—you've just found one of them.

I suggest that you try to use `Net::SSH` instead (which is a very simple wrapper to the system's `ssh` binary) and give it a `ConnectTimeout` and `ServerAliveInterval` options with `-o`, or `Net::OpenSSH` which is referred by @ChankeyPathak above and use its `check_master` method (as I understand from the description, it looks like what you need).

The `ssh_config(1)` manual has a good description of `ConnectTimeout` (which detects timeouts when establishing the connection) and `TCPKeepAlive` and `ServerAliveInterval` (which detect timeouts on the established connection).

For your reference: here is a complete list of options implemented in `Net::SSH::Perl`, grabbed from its `Config.pm`. If you do need to use any other option not listed here, use some other SSH module.

```
BindAddress
Host
BatchMode
ChallengeResponseAuthentication
Cipher
Ciphers
Compression
CompressionLevel
DSAAuthentication
GlobalKnownHostsFile
HostKeyAlgorithms
HostName
IdentityFile
NumberOfPasswordPrompts
PasswordAuthentication
PasswordPromptHost
PasswordPromptLogin
Port
Protocol
RhostsAuthentication
RhostsRSAAuthentication
RSAAuthentication
StrictHostKeyChecking
UsePrivilegedPort
User
UserKnownHostsFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was executing a command that did not terminate for whatever reason. So I wrapped the call to $ssh->cmd in an eval with an alarm as documented in `perldoc -f alarm`. Not the nicest solution but the only option since I can't modify the command I was calling.