# Share variables between Child processes in perl without IPC::Shareable

Tags: perl, variables, fork, shared

I need to share variables between different Children processes and my Parent process in Perl without the use of [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aShareable).

I basically just need to have a global variable that all processes would be able to read/write to.  Also, the variable only needs write access from the parent if that would make my answer simpler.  The Children only need to read it.

Edit: My problem could also be solved if there is a way for me to pass a message from one child process to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you have provided it's difficult to tell which is the best solution, but there are a few options available to you:

- pass a message between your processes using sockets, or pipes
- use a database that both processes read and write to
- use a file(s) that both processes read and write to (you could use signals to tell a process when it is time to read from a file)
- set up a memcache server to share information

---

...However, since your *real* problem might actually be "how can I do something in Perl that requires a module that isn't installed on my system, and I don't have root control over this box and sysadmins can't or won't cooperate?". the best answer is "use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib)", but you can read more options in Matt Trout's blog post ["But I can't use CPAN!"](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/).  (I swear I post this link every single week.)

Comment: Probably better in the long term to link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions instead because it can be more easily improved by the community than mst's article.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html)?

Comment: I was seeing some weird behavior with Perl threading, so I switched to using forks instead. I'm wondering if there is a way I can accomplish this without threads and I unfortunately don't have access to IPC::Shareable =/

Comment: Why don't you have access to IPC::Shareable? It's all right [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BSUGARS/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm) and [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BSUGARS/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable/SharedMem.pm).

Comment: The computers I'm working with are on a closed network and don't come with that package by default.  I could probably get it installed on all my machines if I pushed hard enough, but I was hoping there was another way I could do this.

Comment: My point is you don't need to install it. You can just copy and paste it into your script.