# How do I split a string into an array by comma but ignore commas inside double quotes?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, csv

I have a line:

```
$string = 'Paul,12,"soccer,baseball,hockey",white';
```

I am try to split this into @array that has 4 values so

```
print $array[2];
```

Gives

```
soccer,baseball,hockey
```

How do I this? Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In response to how to do it with Text::CSV(_PP). Here is a quick one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_PP;
my $parser = Text::CSV_PP->new();

my $string = "Paul,12,\"soccer,baseball,hockey\",white";

$parser->parse($string);
my @fields = $parser->fields();

print "$_\n" for @fields;
```

Normally one would install `Text::CSV` or `Text::CSV_PP` through the `cpan` utility.

To work around your not being able to install modules, I suggest you use the 'pure Perl' implementation so that you can 'install' it. The above example would work assuming you copied the text of [Text::CSV_PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_PP) source into a file named `CSV_PP.pm` in a folder called `Text` created in the same directory as your script. You could also put it in some other location and use the `use lib 'directory'` method as discussed previously. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions) and [here](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828) to see other ways to get around install restriction using CPAN modules.

Comment: one more method (though a little more subversive) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user

Answer (score 11):

Just use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-CSV/).  As you can see from [the source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV_PP.pm), getting CSV parsing right is quite complicated:

```
sub _make_regexp_split_column {
    my ($esc, $quot, $sep) = @_;

    if ( $quot eq '' ) {
        return qr/([^\Q$sep\E]*)\Q$sep\E/s;
    }

   qr/(
        \Q$quot\E
            [^\Q$quot$esc\E]*(?:\Q$esc\E[\Q$quot$esc\E0][^\Q$quot$esc\E]*)*
        \Q$quot\E
        | # or
        [^\Q$sep\E]*
       )
       \Q$sep\E
    /xs;
}
```

Comment: There are ways to install modules without install permissions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions. Also if the module is pure-perl, you can simply put it in the same directory as the script, or put it in some directory you have access to and use the `use lib "directory"` contruct, see perldoc.perl.org/lib.html .

Comment: the pure perl implementation is here http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_PP . You can even click on the "source" link and copy/paste it into a file (being careful about naming). That SHOULD work.

Comment: How would I do it using TEXT::CSV?

Comment: @seaworthy, added an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982542/how-do-i-split-a-string-into-an-array-by-comma-but-ignore-commas-inside-double-qu/4984786#4984786

Answer (score 7):

The standard module [Text::ParseWords](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aParseWords) will do this as well.

```
my @array = parse_line(q{,}, 0, $string);
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this existed.

Comment: Text::ParseWords tries to replicate Bourne shell quoting rules, which are not the same as the rules used by most CSV parsers/emitters.  In particular, both single and double quotes are significant, and it uses backslash as an escape character.  So while it works for this specific example, it's a poor choice for CSV parsing.

Comment: The hivemind has inferred that this is a question about CSV parsing. The OP may well be using Bourne shell quoting rules, one of the many extant CSV dialects or a scheme of their own making. Who can say? I was merely trying to answer the question that was actually asked.

Comment: You should have at least mentioned that it also ignores commas inside single quotes, as that's not something the OP asked for, and could come as a big surprise if the data includes apostrophes. (Especially since Text::ParseWords returns an empty list for lines with unbalanced single quotes.)

Comment: I happened to have come back to this from time-to-time, I thought I might comment. When I need light CSV parsing I sometimes use `parse_line` as above, but first I do `$string =~ s|'|\'|g;` works much more as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex: m/("[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?:,\s*)?/g;

The above regular expression globally matches any word that starts with a comma or a quote and then matches the remaining word/words based on the starting character (comma or quote).

Here is a sample code and the corresponding output.

```
my $string = "Word1, Word2, \"Commas, inbetween\", Word3, \"Word4Quoted\", \"Again, commas, inbetween\"";
my @arglist = $string =~ m/("[^"]+"|[^,]+)(?:,\s*)?/g;
map { print $_ , "\n"} @arglist;
```

Here is the output:

```
Word1
Word2
"Commas, inbetween"
Word3
"Word4Quoted"
"Again, commas, inbetween"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  @array=($string =~ /^([^,]*)[,]([^,]*)[,]["]([^"]*)["][,]([^']*)$/);
```

the array will contains the output which expected by you.

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use warning;
#use Data::Dumper;

my $string = qq/Paul,12,"soccer,baseball,hockey",white/;

#split string into three parts
my ($st1, $st2, $st3) = split(/,"|",/, $string);
#output: st1:Paul,12 st2:soccer,baseball,hockey  st3:white  

#split $st1 into two parts
my ($st4, $st5) = split(/,/,$st1);

#push records into array
push (my @test,$st4, $st5,$st2, $st3 ) ;

#print Dumper \@test;
print "$test[2]\n";
```

output:

```
soccer,baseball,hockey 

#$VAR1 = [
#          'Paul',
#         '12',
#          'soccer,baseball,hockey',
#          'white'
#        ];
```

Comment: Interesting? What do I need Data::Dumper for?

Comment: `Data::Dumper` is used just to show array into human readable form.

Comment: Actually [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is used to show a Perl structure in a Perl readable form.

Answer (score -1):

$string = "Paul,12,\"soccer,baseball,hockey\",white";

1 while($string =~ s#"(.*?),(.*?)"#\"$1aaa$2\"#g);

@array = map {$_ =~ s/aaa/ /g; $_ =~ s/\"//g; $_} split(/,/, $string);

$" = "\n";

print "$array[2]";

Comment: Eeeeeek. That's one heavily re-invented (and probably buggy, but who'd bother checking) bicycle. In other words, **please don't write CSV parsers by hand when Text::CSV(_XS) does the job perfectly and has all those freaked out edge and corner cases and bugs already ironed out.**