# Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for `[a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h]`to turn into an array of 6 elements: a, b, c, "d,e,f", g, h. I'm trying to do this through Javascript. This is what I have so far:

```
str = str.split(/,+|"[^"]+"/g);
```

But right now it's splitting out everything that's in the double-quotes, which is incorrect.

Edit: Okay sorry I worded this question really poorly. I'm being given a string not an array.

```
var str = 'a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h';
```

And I want to turn *that* into an array using something like the "split" function.

Comment: Regex isn't really the best tool for this, since regular expressions don't save state.

Comment: @Amber: Then what is the best tool?

Comment: String manipulations, of course! I'm cooking up an answer now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Comment: If for some reason the answers here don't work with your specific use case, as was the case for me, you can try the answer in this duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582276/split-string-by-comma-but-ignore-commas-inside-quotes/23582323

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, I recommend this other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576681/how-can-i-split-by-commas-while-ignoring-any-comma-thats-inside-quotes/57576855#57576855

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Here's what I would do.

```
var str = 'a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h';
var arr = str.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
```

[image]
/* will match:

```
    (
        ".*?"       double quotes + anything but double quotes + double quotes
        |           OR
        [^",\s]+    1 or more characters excl. double quotes, comma or spaces of any kind
    )
    (?=             FOLLOWED BY
        \s*,        0 or more empty spaces and a comma
        |           OR
        \s*$        0 or more empty spaces and nothing else (end of string)
    )
    
*/
arr = arr || [];
// this will prevent JS from throwing an error in
// the below loop when there are no matches
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) console.log('arr['+i+'] =',arr[i]);
```

Comment: Awesome regexp mate. But isn't `/".*"|[^,"\s]+/` enough?

Comment: This won't work on a string like this one: `'Hello World, b, c, "d, e, f", c'`. It returns `["World","b","c","d, e, f", "c"]`

Comment: Good but splits on spaces between words, I amended it to `/(".*?"|[^\s",][^",]+[^\s",])(?=\s*,|\s*$)/`

Comment: to make it work with spaces in between, use the updated form : `(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)` ,  see [this](https://regex101.com/r/lC7iK5/1)

Comment: Does not work when the first column has no data (Export from excel) `,col2_val,col3_val`

Comment: doesn't work for strings like 'a, b, c, blah "d,e,f" blah, g, h' . If something precedes or succeeds quoted content the output arr doesn't seems to have it

Comment: There are extra " for the part within " ". For example, the string 'a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h' become array ["a", "b", "c", ""d, e, f"", "g", "h"].

Comment: The above is great but it returns "d,e,f" in quotes.  Rather than tearing my hair out trying to fix the regex, I did this -   
    var regexp = /(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g;
    var arr = [];
    var res;
    while ((res = regexp.exec(str)) !== null) {
       arr.push(res[0].replace(/(?:^")|(?:"$)/g, ''));
    }
    return arr;

Comment: arkoak's solution does not work with empty values, like ,a,b,c,d (which is common in csv with blank values) https://regex101.com/r/lC7iK5/37 ,a,b,c,d should be an array of 5 values, not 4

Comment: Fixed the issues in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121244/2771889 @m.spyratos zhihong martinp99 Andrew Ted Scheckler

Comment: This also happens to work well for separating a search string by "terms" and "phrases", like `"good fruits" apple banana` -> `['"good fruits"', 'apple', 'banana']`, with a simple modification: `/(".*?"|[^"\s]+)(?=\s*|\s*$)/g`

Comment: Won't work for "Hello",World,"","test" where there is empty string in double quotes

Comment: This doesn't work for strings like `"\"Bananas with chocolate\", Sunday Funday, Tuesday Wednesday"`

It would return ["\"Bananas with chocolate\"", "Sunday", "Funday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]

Comment: Almost works. But this doesn't match empty values when you have consecutive commas `,,,,,`

Comment: @vatsa for this case try [`str.match(/(?:[^",]+|"[^"]*")+/g).map(e => e.trim())`](https://tio.run/##HYzBDsIgEETv/YoNl4Jd6dXYVD/E1ARxhRpaGiA9@e@4epnJZN7M2@wm2zRv5bifag1UIJcEI7QG4YFgWYPxIJ5I@BL/gOAQfNs0PzpRZpo3ejHFetnL6/l2Fzh1H8E@HYTqeqe43STBeAHSJc2LVGpobFxzDKRDdJJ/1FDrFw) @stallingOne to further get empty matches, extend the regex to [`(?:[^",]+|"[^"]*")+|^(?=,)|(?<=,)`](https://regex101.com/r/4lRfKJ/1) (this contains a look*behind* and requires modern JS).

Comment: Does not work for `'a, b, , c, "d, e, f", g, h "i",'`. @f-society [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774647/713573) is working for this case also. Just another round of trim for each is required.

Comment: Can this work on dot instead of comma as well? For e.g. if I had a string as follows: 'a.b.c."d.e.f.",g.h.i' and I wanted the output to be [a, b, c, d.e.f, g, h, i]

Answer (score 42):

regex:  `/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/`

[image]

```
const input_line = '"2C95699FFC68","201 S BOULEVARDRICHMOND, VA 23220","8299600062754882","2018-09-23"'

let my_split = input_line.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/)[4]

Output: 
my_split[0]: "2C95699FFC68", 
my_split[1]: "201 S BOULEVARDRICHMOND, VA 23220", 
my_split[2]: "8299600062754882", 
my_split[3]: "2018-09-23"
```

Reference following link for an explanation: [regexr.com/44u6o](https://regexr.com/44u6o)

Comment: Modified this a bit to now accept values such as `'http://url-to-something.test/1', "Open, this message?", 'Open you sure you want to open this spam message?'`
Sample here: https://regex101.com/r/rzacJ7/1

Answer (score 11):

Here is a JavaScript function to do it:

```
function splitCSVButIgnoreCommasInDoublequotes(str) {  
    //split the str first  
    //then merge the elments between two double quotes  
    var delimiter = ',';  
    var quotes = '"';  
    var elements = str.split(delimiter);  
    var newElements = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {  
        if (elements[i].indexOf(quotes) >= 0) {//the left double quotes is found  
            var indexOfRightQuotes = -1;  
            var tmp = elements[i];  
            //find the right double quotes  
            for (var j = i + 1; j < elements.length; ++j) {  
                if (elements[j].indexOf(quotes) >= 0) {  
                    indexOfRightQuotes = j; 
                    break;
                }  
            }  
            //found the right double quotes  
            //merge all the elements between double quotes  
            if (-1 != indexOfRightQuotes) {   
                for (var j = i + 1; j <= indexOfRightQuotes; ++j) {  
                    tmp = tmp + delimiter + elements[j];  
                }  
                newElements.push(tmp);  
                i = indexOfRightQuotes;  
            }  
            else { //right double quotes is not found  
                newElements.push(elements[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        else {//no left double quotes is found  
            newElements.push(elements[i]);  
        }  
    }  

    return newElements;  
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This works well for me.  (I used semicolons so the alert message would show the difference between commas added when turning the array into a string and the actual captured values.)

**REGEX**

```
/("[^"]*")|[^;]+/
```

[image]

```
var str = 'a; b; c; "d; e; f"; g; h; "i"';
var array = str.match(/("[^"]*")|[^;]+/g); 
alert(array);
```

Comment: This one doesn't correctly parse empty fields like `a;b;;c`

Comment: @DFM: That depends upon what "correctly" means.  Also, the original question implies that there are no ";;" scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a non-regex one that assumes doublequotes will come in pairs:

```js
function splitCsv(str) {
  return str.split(',').reduce((accum,curr)=>{
    if(accum.isConcatting) {
      accum.soFar[accum.soFar.length-1] += ','+curr
    } else {
      accum.soFar.push(curr)
    }
    if(curr.split('"').length % 2 == 0) {
      accum.isConcatting= !accum.isConcatting
    }
    return accum;
  },{soFar:[],isConcatting:false}).soFar
}

console.log(splitCsv('asdf,"a,d",fdsa'),' should be ',['asdf','"a,d"','fdsa'])
console.log(splitCsv(',asdf,,fds,'),' should be ',['','asdf','','fds',''])
console.log(splitCsv('asdf,"a,,,d",fdsa'),' should be ',['asdf','"a,,,d"','fdsa'])
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the regex [we're using](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/62e49f6cdfb77cf86e3b735a7759346b14f5a8d3/etc/regex.md#argument-list) to extract valid arguments from a comma-separated argument list, supporting double-quoted arguments. It works for the outlined edge cases. E.g.

- doesn't include quotes in the matches
- works with white spaces in matches
- works with empty fields

`(?<=")[^"]+?(?="(?:\s*?,|\s*?$))|(?<=(?:^|,)\s*?)(?:[^,"\s][^,"]*[^,"\s])|(?:[^,"\s])(?![^"]*?"(?:\s*?,|\s*?$))(?=\s*?(?:,|$))`

Proof: https://regex101.com/r/UL8kyy/3/tests (*Note: currently only works in Chrome because the regex uses lookbehinds which are only supported in ECMA2018*)

According to [our guidelines](https://github.com/c-hive/guides/blob/62e49f6cdfb77cf86e3b735a7759346b14f5a8d3/etc/regex.md) it avoids non-capturing groups and greedy matching.

I'm sure it can be simplified, I'm open to suggestions / additional test cases.

For anyone interested, the first part matches double-quoted, comma-delimited arguments:

`(?<=")[^"]+?(?="(?:\s*?,|\s*?$))`

And the second part matches comma-delimited arguments by themselves:

`(?<=(?:^|,)\s*?)(?:[^,"\s][^,"]*[^,"\s])|(?:[^,"\s])(?![^"]*?"(?:\s*?,|\s*?$))(?=\s*?(?:,|$))`

Comment: I can't get it to work with empty fields (,,, or ,"","",) so I had to do this first: row = row.split(',').map(p => (p && p || '"_"')).join(',');

Comment: You can change the first part to `(?<=")[^"]*?(?="(?:\s*?,|\s*?$))` to match empty params. E.g. `"foo", "", "bar"` will have 3  matches.

Comment: @thisismydesign Is it possible to modify this to accept empty values within a CSV file as well? For example, test,,hello,goodbye should be have 4 matches.

Comment: @Colin Null I'm sure it can be done but I don't recommend using this to parse CSV. You'd have to think a lot about edge cases, such as escaping the delimiter. Use a library instead.

Answer (score 6):

I almost liked the accepted answer, but it didn't parse the space correctly, and/or it left the double quotes untrimmed, so here is my function:

```js
    /**
     * Splits the given string into components, and returns the components array.
     * Each component must be separated by a comma.
     * If the component contains one or more comma(s), it must be wrapped with double quotes.
     * The double quote must not be used inside components (replace it with a special string like __double__quotes__ for instance, then transform it again into double quotes later...).
     *
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript
     */
    function splitComponentsByComma(str){
        var ret = [];
        var arr = str.match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
        for (let i in arr) {
            let element = arr[i];
            if ('"' === element[0]) {
                element = element.substr(1, element.length - 2);
            } else {
                element = arr[i].trim();
            }
            ret.push(element);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    console.log(splitComponentsByComma('Hello World, b, c, "d, e, f", c')); // [ 'Hello World', 'b', 'c', 'd, e, f', 'c' ]
```

Comment: The only problem with this answer (and I came to find it after a long time after I copied it lol) is that it ignores empty entries such as "test1,,test2". Having nothing in between the commas makes your regex skip it. I ended up using @f-society answer at the end.

Comment: Hi, can you please point me to @f-society's answer. i am looking to split this 'o,"sadasdasd",123123123,"asdasdasd.www.org,123123,link.com",0,,123' into 7 fields.

Answer (score 3):

Parse any CSV or CSV-String code based on TYPESCRIPT

```
public parseCSV(content:string):any[string]{
        return content.split("\n").map(ar=>ar.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/).map(refi=>refi.replace(/[\x00-\x08\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\uFFFF]/g, "").trim()));
    }

var str='"abc",jkl,1000,qwerty6000';

parseCSV(str);
```

output :

```
[
"abc","jkl","1000","qwerty6000"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit long, but here's my take:

```
var sample="[a, b, c, \"d, e, f\", g, h]";

var inQuotes = false, items = [], currentItem = '';

for(var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {
  if (sample[i] == '"') { 
    inQuotes = !inQuotes; 

    if (!inQuotes) {
      if (currentItem.length) items.push(currentItem);
      currentItem = '';
    }

    continue; 
  }

  if ((/^[\"\[\]\,\s]$/gi).test(sample[i]) && !inQuotes) {
    if (currentItem.length) items.push(currentItem);
    currentItem = '';
    continue;
  }

  currentItem += sample[i];
}

if (currentItem.length) items.push(currentItem);

console.log(items);
```

As a side note, it will work both with, and without the braces in the start and end.

Answer (score 1):

This takes a csv file one line at a time and spits back an array with commas inside speech marks intact. if there are no speech marks detected it just .split(",")s as normal... could probs replace that second loop with something but it does the job as is

```
function parseCSVLine(str){
    if(str.indexOf("\"")>-1){
        var aInputSplit = str.split(",");
        var aOutput = [];
        var iMatch = 0;
        //var adding = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<aInputSplit.length;i++){
            if(aInputSplit[i].indexOf("\"")>-1){
                var sWithCommas = aInputSplit[i];
                for(var z=i;z<aInputSplit.length;z++){
                    if(z !== i && aInputSplit[z].indexOf("\"") === -1){
                        sWithCommas+= ","+aInputSplit[z];
                    }else if(z !== i && aInputSplit[z].indexOf("\"") > -1){
                        sWithCommas+= ","+aInputSplit[z];
                        sWithCommas.replace(new RegExp("\"", 'g'), "");
                        aOutput.push(sWithCommas);
                        i=z;
                        z=aInputSplit.length+1;
                        iMatch++;
                    }
                    if(z === aInputSplit.length-1){
                        if(iMatch === 0){
                            aOutput.push(aInputSplit[z]);
                        }                  
                        iMatch = 0;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                aOutput.push(aInputSplit[i]);
            }
        }
        return aOutput
    }else{
        return str.split(",")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the npm library csv-string to parse the strings instead of split: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-string

This will handle the empty entries

Answer (score 0):

Something like a stack should do the trick. Here I vaguely use marker boolean as stack (just getting my purpose served with it).

```
var str = "a,b,c,blah\"d,=,f\"blah,\"g,h,";
var getAttributes = function(str){
  var result = [];
  var strBuf = '';
  var start = 0 ;
  var marker = false;
  for (var i = 0; i< str.length; i++){

    if (str[i] === '"'){
      marker = !marker;
    }
    if (str[i] === ',' && !marker){
      result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
      start = i+1;
    }
  }
  if (start <= str.length){
    result.push(str.substr(start, i - start));
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(getAttributes(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sem0P.png)    [code output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgVnb.png)

The code works if your input string in the format of stringTocompare. 
Run the code on https://jsfiddle.net/ to see output for fiddlejs setting.
Please refer to the screenshot.
You can either use split function for the same for the code below it and tweak the code according to you need.
Remove the bold or word with in ** from the code if you dont want to have comma after split attach=attach**+","**+actualString[t+1].

```
var stringTocompare='"Manufacturer","12345","6001","00",,"Calfe,eto,lin","Calfe,edin","4","20","10","07/01/2018","01/01/2006",,,,,,,,"03/31/2004"';

console.log(stringTocompare);

var actualString=stringTocompare.split(',');
console.log("Before");
for(var i=0;i<actualString.length;i++){
console.log(actualString[i]);
}
//var actualString=stringTocompare.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
for(var i=0;i<actualString.length;i++){
var flag=0;
var x=actualString[i];
if(x!==null)
{
if(x[0]=='"' && x[x.length-1]!=='"'){
   var p=0;
   var t=i;
   var b=i;
   for(var k=i;k<actualString.length;k++){
   var y=actualString[k];
        if(y[y.length-1]!=='"'){        
        p++;
        }
        if(y[y.length-1]=='"'){

                flag=1;
        }
        if(flag==1)
        break;
   }
   var attach=actualString[t];
for(var s=p;s>0;s--){

  attach=attach+","+actualString[t+1];
  t++;
}
actualString[i]=attach;
actualString.splice(b+1,p);
}
}


}
console.log("After");
for(var i=0;i<actualString.length;i++){
console.log(actualString[i]);
}




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FcxM.png
```

Comment: you can add a code snippet directly to your answer see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a simple parser.

It simply goes through the string char by char, splitting off a segment when it finds the split_char (e.g. comma), but also has an on/off flag which is switched by finding the encapsulator_char (e.g. quote). It doesn't require the encapsulator to be at the start of the field/segment (a,b","c,d would produce 3 segments, with 'b","c' as the second), but it should work for a well formed CSV with escaped encapsulator chars.

```
function split_except_within(text, split_char, encapsulator_char, escape_char) {
    var start = 0
    var encapsulated = false
    var fields = []
    for (var c = 0; c < text.length; c++) {
        var char = text[c]
        if (char === split_char && ! encapsulated) {
            fields.push(text.substring(start, c))
            start = c+1
        }
        if (char === encapsulator_char && (c === 0 || text[c-1] !== escape_char) )             
            encapsulated = ! encapsulated
    }
    fields.push(text.substring(start))
    return fields
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hty8Lvr/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
const csvSplit = (line) => {
    let splitLine = [];

    var quotesplit = line.split('"');
    var lastindex = quotesplit.length - 1;
    // split evens removing outside quotes, push odds
    quotesplit.forEach((val, index) => {
        if (index % 2 === 0) {
            var firstchar = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;
            var trimmed = (index == lastindex) 
                ? val.substring(firstchar)
                : val.slice(firstchar, -1);
            trimmed.split(",").forEach(v => splitLine.push(v));
        } else {
            splitLine.push(val);
        }
    });
    return splitLine;
}
```

this works as long as quotes always come on the outside of values that contain the commas that need to be excluded (i.e. a csv file).

if you have stuff like '1,2,4"2,6",8'
it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This code supports single and double quotes, comma separator inside single and double quotes, also empty inside commas.

```
txtArguments = "   1,2,'asd,123', pepe, \"A,B\",,   ";
let acumParam = new Array();
if(txtArguments.trim().length > 0)
{
    let inSQuotes = false;
    let inDQuotes = false;
    let tmpParam = "";                      
    for(let i=0; i<txtArguments.length; ++i)
    {
        const char = txtArguments.substring(i, i+1);
        if(char == "'")
            inSQuotes = inSQuotes ? false : !inDQuotes;
        else if(char == '"')
            inDQuotes = inDQuotes ? false : !inSQuotes;
        if(char == ",")
        {
            if(inSQuotes)
                tmpParam += char;
            else if(inDQuotes)
                tmpParam += char;
            else
            {
                acumParam.push(tmpParam);
                tmpParam = "";
            }
        }
        else
            tmpParam += char;
    }
    acumParam.push(tmpParam);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your string really looks like `'[a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h]'`, I believe this would be 'an acceptable use case for `eval()`:

```
myString = 'var myArr ' + myString;
eval(myString);

console.log(myArr); // will now be an array of elements: a, b, c, "d, e, f", g, h
```

---

**Edit**: As Rocket pointed out, `strict` mode removes `eval`'s ability to inject variables into the local scope, meaning you'd want to do this:

```
var myArr = eval(myString);
```

Comment: Depending on where that string comes from.

Comment: If you're gonna use `eval`, I suggest `var myArr = eval(myString)`.  I think strict mode removes `eval`s ability to inject variables into the local scope.

Comment: Wait.  This won't work as you think.  `eval` will search for the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.  It won't make them strings.

Comment: Hm, it will not work with eval. It will try to evaluate the variables `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP wanted, @bažmegakapa? Unless he wants an array `["a", "b", "c"...]`

Comment: ReferenceError: a is not defined

Answer (score -2):

I've had similar issues with this, and I've found no good .net solution so went DIY. NOTE: This was also used to reply to

[Splitting comma separated string, ignore commas in quotes, but allow strings with one double quotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968720/splitting-comma-separated-string-ignore-commas-in-quotes-but-allow-strings-wit/30081694#30081694)

but seems more applicable here (but useful over there)

In my application I'm parsing a csv so my split credential is ",". this method I suppose only works for where you have a single char split argument.

So, I've written a function that ignores commas within double quotes. it does it by converting the input string into a character array and parsing char by char

```
public static string[] Splitter_IgnoreQuotes(string stringToSplit)
    {   
        char[] CharsOfData = stringToSplit.ToCharArray();
        //enter your expected array size here or alloc.
        string[] dataArray = new string[37];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        bool DoubleQuotesJustSeen = false;          
        foreach (char theChar in CharsOfData)
        {
            //did we just see double quotes, and no command? dont split then. you could make ',' a variable for your split parameters I'm working with a csv.
            if ((theChar != ',' || DoubleQuotesJustSeen) && theChar != '"')
            {
                dataArray[arrayIndex] = dataArray[arrayIndex] + theChar;
            }
            else if (theChar == '"')
            {
                if (DoubleQuotesJustSeen)
                {
                    DoubleQuotesJustSeen = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    DoubleQuotesJustSeen = true;
                }
            }
            else if (theChar == ',' && !DoubleQuotesJustSeen)
            {
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return dataArray;
    }
```

This function, to my application taste also ignores ("") in any input as these are unneeded and present in my input.

Comment: This code will not work here. It is written in Java, but *this* question requires ***javascript***.