# Convert string with commas to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, deserialization

How can I convert a string to a JavaScript array?

Look at the code:

```
var string = "0,1";
var array = [string];
alert(array[0]);
```

In this case `alert` shows `0,1`. If it where an array, it would show `0`. And if `alert(array[1])` is called, it should pop-up `1`

Is there any chance to convert such string into a JavaScript array?

Comment: Depending why you want this, strings and arrays are already very similiar (i.e. `string[0] === '0'` in your question), in most cases you can treat a string as an array of chars and use array methods on it.

Comment: @PaulS.: That will *fail* in IE8 and lower.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert javascript comma separated string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array)

Comment: Best practice for support all types of strings. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32657055/2632619

Answer (score 808, accepted):

For simple array members like that, you can use `JSON.parse`.

```
var array = JSON.parse("[" + string + "]");
```

---

This gives you an Array of numbers.

```
[0, 1]
```

If you use `.split()`, you'll end up with an Array of strings.

```
["0", "1"]
```

---

Just be aware that `JSON.parse` will limit you to the supported data types. If you need values like `undefined` or functions, you'd need to use `eval()`, or a JavaScript parser.

---

If you want to use `.split()`, but you also want an Array of Numbers, you could use `Array.prototype.map`, though you'd need to shim it for IE8 and lower or just write a traditional loop.

```
var array = string.split(",").map(Number);
```

Comment: Also be aware that `JSON.parse();` is not available in IE6, IE7.  I think in this case the `String.split(',');` is easier.

Comment: @scunliffe: True, a shim would be needed, or one could take the jQuery approach to shim it `var array = (new Function("return [" + string + "];"))()`. Using `.split()` is alright if Numbers aren't needed, otherwise you'd need to map the result.

Comment: @Downvoter: Try to describe what is wrong with the answer so that I can demonstrate how you're wrong.

Comment: @I Hate Lazy This doesnt support object string.see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32657055/2632619

Comment: @FarzadYZ Be careful with that (using `eval`). If the array contains values from client side input this will be insecure.

Comment: @Wilt Actually `eval` is always a security concern

Comment: Don't use `JSON.parse` approach, it's never wise to form and evaluate strings into JS. Use `split`+`map`, it's better and elegant.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` worked so perfectly for me. Thank you!
Here is my case:
receivedValue is` "[{name:"Eshwar", area:"Hyd"},{name:"Prasad", area:"India"}]`
So for my unittest case, i did `assert` using `_.isArray(JSON.parse(receivedValue))`

Comment: `string.split(','); `OR `for of & push`

Comment: bad solution!  more info seeing `https://github.com/gildata/RAIO/issues/116#issuecomment-325901359`

Comment: There is an error in this answer. `"0,1".split()` returns `["0,1"]` and **not** `["0", "1"]`. Use `"0,1".split(",")` to return `["0", "1"]`

Comment: this solution not work any more

Comment: JSON.parse dont work for ending comma : `["hbhb, uih", "jggk, ;yg, ugu",]`

Answer (score 162):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it on the `,` character;

```
var string = "0,1";
var array = string.split(",");
alert(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 103):

This is easily achieved in **ES6**;

You can convert strings to Arrays with [Array.from('string')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from);

```
Array.from("01")
```

will console.log

```
['0', '1']
```

Which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This is awesome. I moved my code from `JSON.parse` to `Array.from` as am using `ES6`. Thank you `Ray Kim`

Comment: console.log(typeof Data); //string ==========

        var myArray = Array.from(Data); ============

        console.log(typeof myArray); //Object doesn't support property or method 'from' ==========
Why Is that?

Comment: This is NOT supported in any version of IE. be careful

Comment: But `Array.from("0, 1, 233")` will return `["0", ",", " ", "1", ",", " ", "2", "3", "3"]`, what if I want `[0, 1, 233] ` ?

Comment: bad solution!  more info seeing `https://github.com/gildata/RAIO/issues/116#issuecomment-325901359`

Comment: This is converting every single character as an array element. But we need only comma separated strings to be array elements. So not a valid solution.

Comment: _Is_ there a syntax for converting a comma separated string into a number array using es6 features?

Comment: This method is only reliable when argument is a `Set` of strings.

Answer (score 78):

If the string is already in list format, you can use the JSON.parse:

```
var a = "['a', 'b', 'c']";
a = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
a = JSON.parse(a);
```

Answer (score 29):

### Convert all type of strings

```
var array = (new Function("return [" + str+ "];")());



var string = "0,1";

var objectstring = '{Name:"Tshirt", CatGroupName:"Clothes", Gender:"male-female"}, {Name:"Dress", CatGroupName:"Clothes", Gender:"female"}, {Name:"Belt", CatGroupName:"Leather", Gender:"child"}';

var stringArray = (new Function("return [" + string+ "];")());

var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + objectstring+ "];")());
```

JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/7ne9L4Lj/1/

### Result in console

[image]

### Some practice doesnt support object strings

```
- JSON.parse("[" + string + "]"); // throw error

 - string.split(",") 
// unexpected result 
   ["{Name:"Tshirt"", " CatGroupName:"Clothes"", " Gender:"male-female"}", "      {Name:"Dress"", " CatGroupName:"Clothes"", " Gender:"female"}", " {Name:"Belt"",    " CatGroupName:"Leather"", " Gender:"child"}"]
```

Comment: Great function I also use it but unfortunately it does NOT work for strings or symbols: like e.g. "0,s" any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @sqp_125 try 0,'s' ?

Answer (score 23):

For simple array members like that, you can use JSON.parse.

```
var listValues = "[{\"ComplianceTaskID\":75305,\"RequirementTypeID\":4,\"MissedRequirement\":\"Initial Photo Upload NRP\",\"TimeOverdueInMinutes\":null}]";

var array = JSON.parse("[" + listValues + "]");
```

This gives you an Array of numbers.

now you variable value is like array.length=1

Value output

```
array[0].ComplianceTaskID
array[0].RequirementTypeID
array[0].MissedRequirement
array[0].TimeOverdueInMinutes
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use `split`

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

`"0,1".split(',')`

Answer (score 19):

Another option using the ES6 is using **Spread** syntax.

`var convertedArray  = [..."01234"];`

```js
var stringToConvert = "012";
var convertedArray  = [...stringToConvert];
console.log(convertedArray);
```

Comment: Awesome! Along with Array.from answer they should be the only answers for ES6 solutions.

Answer (score 12):

use the built-in map function with an anonymous function, like so:

```
string.split(',').map(function(n) {return Number(n);});
```

[edit] here's how you would use it

```
var string = "0,1";
var array = string.split(',').map(function(n) {
    return Number(n);
});
alert( array[0] );
```

Comment: This is the most generally applicable answer.  JSON can not be used for arbitrary delimiters (e.g. tab, space, etc)

Comment: This won't work when your array values are string values that possible have a comma inside. For example: `"123, 'a string with a , comma', 456"`. You could use a more complex regex to handle such cases correctly (for example something like suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript)).

Comment: @Wilt well no it wouldn't, but yeah you could use regex to fix that

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your answer, but I wrote this because I used your solution and ran into this issue myself. Thought of leaving the comment for others possibly running into similar problems.

Comment: Could be shortened as follows `string.split(',').map(Number)`

Answer (score 5):

I remove the characters '[',']' and do an split with ','

```
let array = stringObject.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",").map(String);
```

Answer (score 5):

More "Try it Yourself" examples below.

Definition and Usage
The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.

Note: The split() method does not change the original string.

```
var res = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert string to an array. In the solution below, I remove the comma then convert the string to an array.

```
var string = "0,1"
var array = [...string.replace(',', '')]
console.log(array[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Regexp

As more powerful alternative to `split`, you can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
"0,1".match(/\d+/g)
```

```js
let a = "0,1".match(/\d+/g)

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = "[{a:1,b:2}]",
    j = i.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+?):/g, '"$1":').replace(/'/g,'"'),
    k = JSON.parse(j);

console.log(k)
```

**//** => declaring regular expression

**[a-zA-Z0-9]** => match all a-z, A-Z, 0-9

**():** => group all matched elements

**$1** => replacement string refers to the first match group in the regex.

**g** => global flag

Answer (score 1):

Split (",") can convert Strings with commas into a String array, here is my code snippet.

```
    var input ='Hybrid App, Phone-Gap, Apache Cordova, HTML5, JavaScript, BootStrap, JQuery, CSS3, Android Wear API'
    var output = input.split(",");
    console.log(output);
```

> ["Hybrid App", " Phone-Gap", " Apache Cordova", " HTML5", "
>   JavaScript", " BootStrap", " JQuery", " CSS3", " Android Wear API"]

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do replace `,` comma and `split('')` the string like this which will result into `['0', '1']`, furthermore, you could wrap the result into `parseInt()` to transform element into integer type.

```
it('convert string to array', function () {
  expect('0,1'.replace(',', '').split('')).toEqual(['0','1'])
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Example using `Array.filter`:

```
var str = 'a,b,hi,ma,n,yu';

var strArr = Array.prototype.filter.call(str, eachChar => eachChar !== ',');
```