# Set Javascript Array in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is generated in PHP:

```
<div id='container1' data-history="[["test", "test title", "", []]]">
```

I wish to have this accessible in javascript but when I use console.log(history[0]) it outputs '[' so its treating the array as a string.

Is there a way to have it so that javascript can read it as an array?

My PHP code is as follows (i removed the slashes and '' around the array)

```
echo '<div id="container1" data-history=[[0]["test", "test title", "", []]] data-current-url="'.$url.'">';
```

Comment: how are you doing `echo` for data-history attribute value from php?

Comment: Yes I am using echo from PHP

Comment: `echo` is fine, but how are you doing that for array? plz provide php code

Comment: check dis, for that you need to make your array valid `json`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/javascript-string-to-array-conversion

Comment: I updated the array bit but now it gives me: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword

Comment: Updated again it gives me this error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Comment: why don't you just use `echo json_encode($php_array);` ?

Comment: like, `echo '<div id="container1" data-history="'.json_encode($php_array).'" data-current-url="'.$url.'">';`

Comment: @anni I have reversed your edit. Not only did it have nothing to do with "fromating", but it also introduced tags that don't seem particularly relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you removed the `\` characters from it and added a `,` after the first array element, then it would be valid JSON and you could pass it through `JSON.parse()`.

```
  <div id='container1' data-history='[[0],["test", "test title", "", []]]'></div>
  <script>
    var history = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('container1').getAttribute('data-history'));
    console.log(history);
    alert(history[1][1]);
  </script>
```

From a comment on another answer:

> Its meant to be a multi dimensional array where index 0 contains `'["test", "test title", "", []]'`

You don't specify the property names in JavaScript or JSON array literal syntax. The position determines the property name.

```
data-history='[["test", "test title", "", []]]'>
```

Comment: Ok I did that and it gives me this error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data". My new code: data-history=[[0]["test", "test title", "", []]]

Comment: You've removed the `'` characters from around the attribute value. Don't do that. Attribute values containing spaces must be quoted.

Comment: hmm, you are also missing a comma after the first array element

Answer (score 0):

Besides the escape characters (that are to be removed), the following string is not regular JSON:

```
[[0]["test", "test title", "", []]]
```

So eventually it won't be parsed by `JSON.parse()`.
Maybe you ment following form:

```
[[0, "test", "test title", "", []]]
```

That is correctly parsed by `JSON.parse()`:

```
var dataHistory = JSON.parse('[[0, "test", "test title", "", []]]');
```

**EDIT**

As for the multidimensional array, there are several possibilities:

1. use the natural position of the elements:

   ```
   var dataHistory = [
     ["test", "test title", "", []]    //this is the 0 element
   ];
   var myZeroElement = dataHistory[0];
   ```
2. use a key, value structure:

   ```
   var dataHistory = [
     {'key':'0', 'value': ["test", "test title", "", []]}
   ];
   var myZeroElement = dataHistory[0].value;
   ```

Comment: Its meant to be a multi dimensional array where index 0 contains '["test", "test title", "", []]'

Comment: I've changed it to your first suggestion but it gives me this error:SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword

Comment: Please post the code you use to grab the `data-history` attribute value and to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Since both javascript and php have the same two types of quotes to delimitate strings, you need to escape some of them:

```
echo '<div id="container1" data-history=\'[[0],["test", "test title", "", []]]\' data-current-url="'.$url.'">';
```

Comment: I had at the start but apparently that wasn't valid according to answers.

Comment: Oh yes, there is a missing comma

Answer (score -1):

This data is not valid JSON string. You can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/

In PHP use `json_encode($table);` to encode your array to a valid JSON string and put it in your HTML attribute.

Then use `JSON.parse(history)` in your JS to get the corresponding JSON object.

EDIT:
Try to change your php to this:

```
echo '<div id="container1" data-history="[\"test\", \"test title\", \"\"]" data-current-url="'.$url.'">';
```

And use the JS code I supplied.