# How to convert this string to an array

Tags: javascript

I need to convert this string to an array:

```
var mystring = "[-item1,item2]";
```

This is handed to me as a string. Is there a javascript function that can convert this? If not how would you suggest putting item1 and item2 in an array?

Comment: Are `item1` and `item2` variables or are they actual values embedded in the string (e.g. `[-5, 7]`)?

Comment: You want the literal string "item1", "item2" in an array? or the variables? If the latter, what scope are they in?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/javascript-string-to-array-conversion

Comment: The whole string is a literal that needs converting

Comment: Couldn't you just JSON.parse it?

Comment: @Luke101 - Converting from what? Are `item1` and `item2` variable names or strings?

Comment: So you're given the string `'[-item1,item2]'`. But what is it supposed to convert _to_? What is the resulting array supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the split() Method:

I would first remove the first and last character in order to get rid of the "[" and"]"

then:

```
var str = "-item1,item2";
var res = str.split(",");
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

```
[-item1,item2]
```

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ac42qs2/1/

```
    var mystring = "[-item1,item2]";

    var arr = mystring.replace('\[', "").replace('\]', "").split(',')

    alert(arr[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `text1` and `text2` are not var's but literal's you will need to add quotes.
Use `JSON.parse` to create objects from strings:

```
var numbers = '[-1,2]';
var mystring = '["text1","text2"]';
var numbersArr = JSON.parse(numbers);
var stringsArr = JSON.parse(mystring);
console.log(numbersArr);
console.log(stringsArr);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mfn6eqLc/).