# php output to javascript array with json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a project that spits out a json_encode string of date items.

Looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="avail_dates" data-id='["12-9-2014", "7-9-2014"]' />
```

I've tried different things, but because of this project it has to be there, I can't simply do an ajax call and return the json_encode stuff.

So, I need to get the data-id into a javascript array somehow for a datePicker.

Using this works, but it's hard coded:

```
var availableDates = ["9-9-2014","5-9-2014","7-9-2014"];
```

Using this doesn't do anything:

```
var availableDatesArray = jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id'); 
//alerting gives ["9-9-2014","5-9-2014","7-9-2014"]
```

Is there a way to convert the string into an array that works?

I can change the way the data gets into the data-id, or the way jquery interacts with the element, but I can't add a separate ajax query just for this, it has to come from that data-id.

```
var availableDates = ["9-9-2014","5-9-2014","7-9-2014"];    

function dates(date){
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    console.log(dmy+' : '+(jQuery.inArray(dmy, availableDates)));
    if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
        return [true, "","Available"];
    } 
    else {
        return [false,"","unAvailable"];
    }           
    return;
}

jQuery('#myDates').datepicker({
changeYear: true,
maxDate: '0',
changeMonth: true,
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
yearRange: '2014:2030',
beforeShowDay: dates,       
onSelect: function(dateText) {

}
});
```

EDIT:
Should have mention I already tried json.parse. It gives an "unexpected number" error.

EDIT 2: I added the function I'm trying to pass the data too for jQuery datePicker.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/javascript-string-to-array-conversion

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your "unexpected number" error using `JSON.parse`. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @David, JSON.parse works fine here using html shown  http://jsfiddle.net/js3qnae1/

Comment: @David, well most likely there is some missing piece you're not telling us, as it stands, using your example, using JSON.parse, and .data will work just fine

Comment: see edits, I added the functions I'm using to pass it to. When it's hard coded it works fine, dymanically not at all. json.parse gives an error

Comment: @David put it in a fiddle , has already been shown that it can work

Comment: @David which language renders the values inside `data-id=""` is it PHP? `data-id="<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>"`?

Comment: exactly correct. Also, don't know how to include the datePicker library, so.. ya sorry. no fiddle

Comment: Ghost's example will result in invalid HTML, since the JSON will contain full quotes. Is that exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @David thats odd, should be working fine. anyway, i'l give a long shot: `data="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)); ?>"`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara perfectly acceptable to wrap attribute values in single quotes as shown in OP

Comment: json.parse works. There was a bad database entry beginning the array with junk data. The php was trying to strip it out, but it resulted in a javascript error.

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure I understand what you are saying, but `"`'s are fine for attribute wrapping, putting them unencoded inside an attribute using them (i.e. JSON encoded strings) causes problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, use `JSON.parse`. Like this:

```
var availableDatesArray = jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id'); 
availableDatesArray = JSON.parse(availableDatesArray);
console.log(availableDatesArray);
```

Or much better suggestion of @charlie

```
var availableDatesArray = jQuery('.avail_dates').data('id'); // much better
```

Comment: no need to use `JSON.parse()`, if use `jQuery.data()` will read it as array if it is valid JSON and parse it internally

Comment: Should have mention I already tried json.parse. It gives an "unexpected number" error

Comment: Doesn't work. Formats as "9-9-2014,5-9-2014,7-9-2014", apparently I need the brackets and double quotes for this function to work

Comment: @David what is the origin of that data anyway? is PHP echoing that?, as your question stands in the current posting, its working fine.

Comment: @David You have `[]`'s in your example. Are they not present or something you want to remove?

Comment: @David thats a good point from Alexander, maybe append it after getting it thru .attr: `var availableDatesArray = '['+jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id')+']';`

Comment: Then the quotes aren't there

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

**Example:**

```
var availableDatesArray = JSON.parse(jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id'));
```

If you prefer, you can use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

**Example:**

```
var availableDatesArray = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id'));
```

This is actually how jQuery itself parses JSON in AJAX responses.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you just need to use `JSON.parse`:

```
var availableDatesArray = JSON.parse(jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id'));
```

`jQuery('.avail_dates').attr('data-id')` is just going to return a string (the contents of the 'data-id' attribute. `JSON.parse` will actually create a JavaScript object from it.