# Convert special String to an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have strings like this :

```
var S1 = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]";
var S2 = "[ \"2\" ]";
var S3 = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\" ]";
```

And I want to convert them under JavaScript to an Array like this :

```
var S1a = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
var S2a = ['2'];
var S3a = ['1','2','3'];
```

Please how can I achieve the above ?

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @Jean Alex answered!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for this

Write your code as follow:

```
var S1 = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]";
var arr = JSON.parse(S1);
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13272437/5928577)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun you can also do l like this. If you want the resulting array to contain integers instead of string characters then just do `r.concat(+e)` instead of `r.concat(e)`

```js
var s = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]",
    a = s.split(/\[*\s*\"(\d+)\",*\s*\]*/).reduce((r,e,i) => i%2 ? r.concat(e) : r,[]);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can JSON parse like :

```
JSON.parse("[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]");
```

output will be : `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]`

> Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/us9L1ed0/
>
> JSON.parse Reference :
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse
>   http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp
>
> Code Snippet as per your example

```
var S1 = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\" ]";
var S2 = "[ \"2\" ]";
var S3 = "[ \"1\", \"2\", \"3\" ]";

var S1a =JSON.parse(S1)
var S2a=JSON.parse(S2)
var S3a = JSON.parse(S3)

console.log(S1a);
console.log(S2a);
console.log(S3a);
```