# Convert string of array, with array of array(s)

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: `var data = "[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]]";`
I am using the well known blossom function, which expects (as input) an array of this type: `[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]], [...], [...]]`

As you can see, I am trying to provide this with my: `data` variable, but this is currently a string, so I need to convert it to the right type. I know that I can convert a string to an array like this:

```
var input = "1, 2, 3";
var array = input.split(",");
```

Then the result of the above will be: `["1", "2", "3"]`

But I need to be able to give input like this: `var data = "[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]]";`
And expect this output: `[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]];`
Also, notice that the values in the brackets are numbers and not string.

I also tried doing this:

`var data = "[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]";
 var res = data.split(",");`

This gives the output: `["[1", " 2", " 3", "]", " [3", " 2", " 1]"]`

Finally I also found this example: [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/javascript-string-to-array-conversion)  where the solution made use of JSON.parse(...), but I did not make this work either.

Comment: Is the trailing comma in the first array a typo ? If not it will make it harder to use `JSON.parse`. If it is then just go for it.

Comment: No, the commas are not a type :)

Comment: If you control and trust the source of the data, you can use `Function` constructor as a substitute for `eval`. It evaluates the code just like any other script, hence the trust caveat, but by using `Function` it at least gets eval'd as though the function was created in the global scope, and it avoids performance problems. `var array = new Function("return " + data)();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array have trailing commas you can use this code:

```js
var data = "[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]]";
var array = JSON.parse(data.replace(/,\s*]/g, ']'));
console.log(array);
```

and if you have string like this:

```
var data = "[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]";
```

use

```
var array = JSON.parse('[' + data.replace(/,\s*]/g, ']') + ']');
```

Example:

```js
var data = "[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]";
var array = JSON.parse('[' + data.replace(/,\s*]/g, ']') + ']');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This give the output: "1,2,3,3,2,1". It's as if it ignores the brackets?

Comment: @MOR_SNOW: No, it doesn't. It gives you an array. Apparently the way you're **outputting** that array makes it look like that.

Comment: I need it to output this:  "[[1,2,3,3,2,1]]". I could add those manually of course, but maybe you know a smarter way to it, in addition to the code you provided?

Comment: @MOR_SNOW: That isn't the output you show in the question.

Comment: Never mind, it's correct as you provided already. I missed something. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, this isn't JSON, as there are trailing commas.

Modifying a string which isn't in JSON to make it possible to use `JSON.parse` looks like a silly hack, especially when a proper parsing is easy.

An alternative would be:

```
var arr = str.split(/[\[\]]+,?\s*/)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .map(s=>s.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean).map(Number));
```

Comment: That adds a 0 to the end of the first array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, fixed