# Parse a string with int and float to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a string that I convert to an array:

```
var data = "[[1, 2, 3,], [3, 2, 1]]";
var array = JSON.parse(data.replace(/,\s*]/g, ']'));
```

I need to be able to handle floating points, i.e input of this form:

```
var data = "[[2.,23.,1.5904], [4.,23,1.6208]]";
```

Using the browser console, when I try to do:

`var ar = JSON.parse(data.replace(/,\s*]/g, ']'));`

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated fractional number at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data
```

I guess it has something to do with the regexp of the `JSON.parse()`, but I am not strong in regexp yet, so I don't have a clue.

I have played around with this: https://regexone.com/  which actually helped understanding pretty much, but I'm still not able to fix my problem.

This question is kind of an extension to my previous question (which is solved):

[Convert string of array, with array of array(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748301/convert-string-of-array-with-array-of-arrays)

What I didn't think of at the time, was that I also need to be able to handle floating points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JSON needs a number after a dot.

The correct JSON will be this way:

```
var data = "[[2.0,23.0,1.5904], [4.0,23,1.6208]]";
```

So you must either output full float numbers (if you have control over the output) or parse the string to append zeroes to all dots, like this:

```
data.replace(/\.,/g, ".0,").replace(/\.]/g, ".0]");
```

Note that we need to also look for dots near `]`, not only commas.

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly fix this with

```
data.replace(/\.,/g, ".0,)
```

This replaces every `.,` in `2.,` to `2.0,`

Or you can do

```
data.replace(/\.,/g, ",")
```

Which removes the dots before the commas.