# Inverse of array.toString () Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
var bestArray = ["Veni", "vidi", "vici"];
```

Now, I use the method `toString ()` in order to traduce the array to a string like this:

```
var bestString = bestArray.toString(); // "Veni, vidi, vici"
```

Here, my code works fine. But, now I want to traduce `bestString` to an array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: by splitting with comma

Comment: Be careful to never have a `,` in one of your strings though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Array.join` and `Arrat.split` instead:

```js
var bestArray = ["Veni", "vidi", "vici"];

var joined = bestArray.join(",");
console.log(joined);

var split = joined.split(",");
console.log(split);
```

**Note**: `Array.split` will give you incorrect results if your source array has elements containing a comma (`,`).

So, if you do not plan to represent the array string to a GUI, you should use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 2):

Split it by comma `,`

```
["Veni", "vidi", "vici"].toString().split(",");
```

output is `["Veni", "vidi", "vici"]` again.

**Demo**

```js
["Veni", "vidi", "vici"].toString().split(","); 

var inputArr = ["Veni", "vidi", "vici"];

console.log( "toString ", inputArr.toString() ) ;

console.log( "back to array ", inputArr.toString().split(",") ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split(,)`

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
var bestArray = ["Veni", "vidi", "vici"];
var sArray = bestArray.toString();
console.log(sArray);

var arrayAgain = sArray.split(",");
console.log(arrayAgain);
```