# How to put an arrays into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I am taking from backend that is like

```
["[a,b,c],[c,d,e],[e,f,g]"]
```

I am taking this array in

```
<div id="op1">{{$option}}</div>
```

now I want to add more items into it when I access it in javascript using

```
document.getElementById('op1').innerHTML
```

and add this into an array

```
var options=[document.getElementById('op1').innerHTML];
```

and when I print it using

```
console.log(options)
```

it shows me

```
["[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]"]
```

type of array other than

```
[[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]
```

so how I can get this type of array and more items into it.

Comment: And what is `[[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]`? What does it represent, what are `a`, `b`? Are they strings or variables or letters? You would be able to parse if it was a valid JSON, but in this case it is unclear what you want to be stored in your `options` after reading this input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Comment: And why don't you also pass it to a javascript variable in a script tag instead of trying to parse it from html text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this answer is optimal solution but I have tried to bring a solution that nearly fits your requirements:

```js
var arr = ["[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]"];
var res = [];
arr[0].split('[').forEach((splitVal) => {
  if (splitVal) {
    var arrInner = [];
    var commaSplit = splitVal.split(',');
    commaSplit.forEach((commaSplitVal) => {
      if (commaSplitVal) {
        arrInner.push(commaSplitVal.replace(']', ''));
      }
    });
    res.push(arrInner);
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The state of your data specified above `["[a,b,c],[c,d,e],[e,f,g]"]` is a JS Array with 1 item, which is a string.  The string contains a comma separated list of arrays.

You can use `String.prototype.split` to split the string into arrays by a separator like such

```
var options=[document.getElementById('op1').innerHTML];
var arrayYouWant = options.map(item => item.split(','));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split