# Split string into array that has brackets in string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string in this format:

```
"[0.00,0.10],[3.00,0.10],[6.00,0.10],[9.00,0.10],[12.00,662.00],[15.00,1186.00]"
```

I want to split it into an array so that the final array would look like this.  Basically they are `[x,y]` pairs to use in a highcharts chart.

```
[[0.00,0.10], [3.00,0.10], [6.00,0.10], [9.00,0.10], [12.00,662.00], [15.00,1186.00]]
```

Using javascript how is this possible?

I have tried using regular expression, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could add brackets and parse as [JSON](http://json.org/) with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
var string =  "[0.00,0.10],[3.00,0.10],[6.00,0.10],[9.00,0.10],[12.00,662.00],[15.00,1186.00]",
    array = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');
    
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```