# Function keeps returning 0 when I call it from inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function to compare to list in javaScript

```
function listCompare(list1, list2) {
    let result = 0;
    let final = (list1.length + list2.length) / 2;
    for (let x of list1) {
        for (let y of list2) {
            if (x == y) {
                result += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result / final * 100;
};
```

Its work just fine alone but when call it inside another function it return only zero. I don't know why this is the full code

```
function listCompare(list1, list2) {
    let result = 0;
    let final = (list1.length + list2.length) / 2;
    for (let x of list1) {
        for (let y of list2) {
            if (x == y) {
                result += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result / final * 100;
};

$('#id_password').change(function() {
    // console.log('changed')
    ls1 = time
    ls2 = ob
    var result = listCompare(ls1, ls2)
    console.log(result)
    if (result >= 70) {
    $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
     }


});
```

note: I have two list one of them is time the author on is ob the function shode  return the degree of matching between the two list and five to me

```
var test1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
var test2 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80];
var test3 = [12,41,85,75,23,99,81,1236];
var test4 = [41,59,830,10,51,16,78,81];
console.log(listCompare(test1,test2))
output : 100
console.log(listCompare(test3,test4))
Output: 25
console.log(listCompare(test1,test4))
Output: 12.5
```

Comment: do you have some data and result for/of the function?

Comment: yes i have some data

Comment: i suspect `time` and `ob` are empty. thus `return 0 / 0 * 100;` would be `0`

Comment: nice, that you have some data. do you mind to add this data and result?

Comment: if you read the note time and ob are list

Comment: add it to the question?

Comment: ok i have add the data

Comment: do you have only unique values in the arrays?

Comment: its shode look like each other

Comment: where do you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, everyone, the problem was one of the var return as a string so I hade to convert it to list you will find the answer here[enter link description here][1]

[][1]: [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to look at how many elements the `time` and `ob` variables contain at runtime. `alert(time.length+','+ob.length);`. I don't see you assigning any values to those variables in your `$('#id_password').change` function