# Parse HTML String to Array

Tags: javascript

I have an html string that contains multiple `<p>` tags. WIthin each `<p>` tag there is a word and its definition.

```
let data = "<p><strong>Word 1:</strong> Definition of word 1</p><p><strong>Word 2:</strong> Definition of word 2</p>"
```

My goal is to convert this html string into an array of objects that looks like below:

```
[
 {"word": "Word 1", "definition": "Definition of word 1"},
 {"word": "Word 2", "definition": "Definition of word 2"}
]
```

I am doing it as follows:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
  var parsedHtml    = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
  let pTags = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("p");
  let vocab = []
  pTags.forEach(function(item){
    // This is where I need help to split and convert item into object
    vocab.push(item.innerHTML)
  });
```

As you can see the comment in the above code, that is where I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please create and share a fiddle which can describe what you tried to do

Comment: How about this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array#answer-32657055?

Comment: @manfromnowhere That's not about parsing HTML, it's JSON.

Comment: Can you change the HTML to put a tag around the definition, like `<span class="definition">Definition of word 1</span>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `textContent` to get the text out of an element. The word is in the `strong` child element, the definition is the rest of the text.

```
var parser = new DomParser();
  var parsedHtml    = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
  let pTags = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("p");
  let vocab = []
  pTags.forEach(function(item){
    let word = item.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].textContent.trim();
    let allText = item.textContent;
    let definition = allText.replace(word, "").trim();
    vocab.push({word: word, definition: definition})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit adhoc but works.

```js
const data = "<p><strong>Word 1:</strong> Definition of word 1</p><p><strong>Word 2:</strong> Definition of word 2</p>";
const parsedData = [
  {
    "word1": data.split('<strong>')[1].split('</strong>')[0].trim(),
    "definition": data.split('</strong>')[1].split('</p>')[0].trim()
  },
  {
    "word2": data.split('</p>')[1].split('<strong>')[1].split('</strong>')[0].trim(),
    "definition": data.split('</p>')[1].split('</strong>')[1].split('</p>')[0].trim()
  }
]
console.log(parsedData);
```

Comment: Going from a DOM parser to string function is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix:

- `DOMParser`, not `DomParser`
- `pTags` cannot use `.forEach()`, please use `for` loop

My solution for your problem:

```js
let data = "<p><strong>Word 1:</strong> Definition of word 1</p><p><strong>Word 2:</strong> Definition of word 2</p>"

var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
let pTags = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("p");
let vocab = [];
for (let p of pTags) {
  const word = p.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML.replace(':', '').trim();
  const definition = p.innerHTML.replace(/<strong>.*<\/strong>/, '').trim();
  vocab.push( { word, definition } )
}

console.log(vocab);
```