# How to loop over array entered in an input and categorize based on their type?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I'm trying to let user input an array in an `<input>`. Then I would sort them into different arrays based on their data types; (number, strings and booleans).

But I cant figure out how to loop through the input to sort them out.
  **Example input is : [1,"bad",false,3,"key"]**

EXTRA: If you can help complete code. This the source code :[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pelumi_js/pen/YBorNP?editors=1010)

```js
function sort() {
  const numbers = [];
  const strings = [];
  const booleans = [];
  const others = [];
  const inpArr = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
  //console.log(inpArr.value);
  for (let i = 0; i < inpArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(inpArr[i].value);
    switch (typeof inpArr[i].value) {
      case "Number":
        numbers.push(inpArr[i].value);
        break;

      default:
        console.log(typeof inpArr[i].value)
    }
  }

  const objectResult = {
    "Strings": strings,
    "Numbers": numbers,
    "Booleans": booleans,
    "Others": others

  };

  const JsonObj = JSON.stringify(objectResult)
  document.querySelector("#rawResult").innerText = JsonObj;

}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <input class="input" placeholder="Enter an Array" />
  <button onclick="sort()">SORT ARRAY</button>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div id="rawResult"></div>
  <div id="tableResult"></div>
</div>
```

I need how to loop through the inpArr and sort each values into their respective arrays. and show the user as object

Comment: `typeof inpArr[i].value` will always return `string`

Comment: You only have one `input` with a class of `input`, so you'll only have one value in your array...

Comment: i'm surprised why are we pushing to constant variables  else why are we using const variable here

Comment: how can i fix this please?

Comment: @adiga how can i fix this>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is a sample of the input entered in the `input`? Are you entering them separated by a comma? Do you want to try to *parse* the input to numbers, booleans in some order and settle for `string` at the end?

Comment: If you're asking a user to enter an array, they'll likely enter "1,2,3". If you want to parse that as an array. see the dupe

Comment: example of the input is [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion you can push to a `const` array variable. Only reassignment is not allowed

Comment: you can do it with reducer or map or filter

Comment: Also, please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answers and comments posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using `JSON.parse`. I have changed the name of the `objectResult` keys and made it similar to what `typeof` returns so that it's easier to sort them into different categories using `[]` brackets. You can use a `switch` instead if you want custom keys like `Others`

```js
function sort() {
  const numbers = [];
  const strings = [];
  const booleans = [];
  const others = [];
  const value = document.querySelectorAll(".input")[0].value;
  let inputArray

  try {
    inputArray = JSON.parse(value)
  } catch {
    alert("Please enter a valid JSON string")
    return;
  }

  const objectResult = {
    "string": strings,
    "number": numbers,
    "boolean": booleans,
  };

  inputArray.forEach(item => {
    objectResult[typeof item].push(item)
  });

  const JsonObj = JSON.stringify(objectResult)
  document.querySelector("#rawResult").innerText = JsonObj;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <input class="input" placeholder="Enter an Array" value='[1,"bad",false,3,"key"]' />
  <button onclick="sort()">SORT ARRAY</button>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <div id="rawResult"></div>
  <div id="tableResult"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i get this error :  Unexpected token, expected ( (12:8)

Comment: On which line exactly? It works fine here on the snippet. Click on `Run code snippet` to test it out

Comment: the line you wrote } catch {

Comment: sorry for late reply

Comment: @Pelumi it works in the snippet without an issue. There was an additional `()` after `catch` when I posted but I removed it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do by `typeof` , you can do by some simple method like `isNaN`, for boolean I think you need to check exact string for `true or false` or other will string ...

```
if(!isNaN(inpArr[i].value)) { //Number
　　numbers.push(inpArr[i].value);
} else if(inpArr[i].value == "true" || inpArr[i].value == "false") { // boolean
   booleans.push(inpArr[i].value);
} else { // String
   strings.push(inpArr[i].value);
}
```

Comment: i think my for loop is the problem