# How to split string and create an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let name = "Stack Overflow"
```

I want to ignore space and create an array with each alphabet as an element.

Expected result: `["S", "t", "a", "c", "k", "O", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "o", "w"]`

Comment: I would try with `name.split('').filter(e => e !== ' ')` or maybe with `name.replace(' ', '').split('')`.

Comment: This is duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array

Comment: What is expected result? I though its `["S", "t", "a", "c", "k", "O", "v", "e", "r", "f", "l", "o", "w"]`

Comment: @Soham yes you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log("Stack Overflow".replace(/\s/g, '').split(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

On javascript you're looking for [spread (link to docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator associate with a [filter method (link to docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

The spread will create an array with all chars from your string, the filter will ignore all spaces for you:

```js
let name = "Stack Overflow"

let myArray = [...name].filter(letter => letter !== ' ');

// myArray will be:
[
  'S', 't', 'a', 'c',
  'k', 'O', 'v', 'e',
  'r', 'f', 'l', 'o',
  'w'
]
```

This also right for es6 ! Cheer

Comment: _I want to ignore space and create an array with each alphabet_

Answer (score -1):

```
name.replace(/ /g,'')
```

And then

```
Array.from(name)
```