# jquery output to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, type-conversion

I am displaying the content of data_R in a selector using jquery:

```
  $("#output").text(data_R)
```

This works nicely and the selector indeed displays what is expected:

```
0.01,0.02,0.0301,0.0401,0.0501,0.0601
```

I am wondering how to convert this text to an array. Say

```
[0.01,0.02,0.0301,0.0401,0.0501,0.0601]
```

That I can use as a variable somewhere else.

Thanks

Comment: Use split on ','

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)