# Can Google chart data.addRows() accept data literraly?

Tags: javascript, graph

I have a google chart and would like to add data ***var mydata*** into the data.AddRow().

```html
<script>
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'one');
    data.addColumn('number', 'two');
    data.addColumn('number', 'three');
    data.addColumn('number', 'four');
    var mydata = '[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]';
    data.addRows([
      mydata
    ]);
    ......
</script>
```

I get an error on the console as follows:

> jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:182 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 0 is not null or an array.

JSON.parse() is also not working in this case. What can I do to accept the data into the google chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

went you wrote

```
var mydata = '[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]';
```

mydata is a **string**

to define mydata as list of list use (note opening and closing bracket)

```
var mydata = [ [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12] ];
```

then use without nesting bracket.

```
data.addRows(mydata);
```

note that <s>mydata = [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]</s> (neither quote, nor bracket) isn't a valid javascipt syntax.

---

related information available in [convert string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array) (note thet in your case, you will have to use a loop you inner array).