# Find string can be array

Tags: javascript

I got a result like this :

```
const result = [ 'arg', 'arg2', '[opt1, opt2]' ]
```

How can I check in this array if a string can be a array ('[opt1, opt2]') and formate it in real array ?

Thank you

EDIT :

I explain all problem :

I want create a script :

```
yarn start arg1 arg2 "[option1, option2]"
```

I need a array of options but I can have a lot args without restrictions, when I recover the result :

```
const res = process.argv.slice(2)
```

How can I find my array of options ?

Comment: why do you have an array into a string? if you take the array out of the string you can do a type check. [ 'arg', 'arg2', ['opt1', 'opt2'] ]

Comment: even if you evaluate the string to an array you will get an reference error because `opt1` isnt defined. Or is this also an string?

Comment: If the string-array is not json or other known format, you may need to build your own parser.

Comment: does this link below help:
[Format String Into Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Comment: please check the update in my answer. It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution with string manipulation

```js
const result = ['arg', 'arg2', "[option1, option2]"]

const output = result.map(item => {
  if (/^\[.+\]$/.test(item)) {
    const prepared = item
      .replace('[', '["')
      .replace(']', '"]')
      .replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+),+\s+/g, '$1", "')
    return JSON.parse(prepared)
  }
  return item
})

console.log(output)
```

Explanation:

- `/^\[.+\]$/` regex - checks whether the element is an array (based on the presence of matching square brackets)
- all other replace statements change the string into valid string encoded JSON array.

Since the overall result is a valid string encoded JSON array, just use `JSON.parse` after that and `return` it.