# Convert JSON data to JSON data with an array replacing string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following data:

```
{
"action":"Profile Updates",
"candidate_id":"1234",
"docs_verified":"ABC",
"skills":"PROF1_EN, blah, test"
}
```

I need the data in JSON format but I need the skills section as an array... how can I convert this JSON to one which has the skills section as an array?

I can separate just the skills but I'm unsure how to return this:

```
{
    "action": "Profile Updates",
    "candidate_id": "1234",
    "docs_verified": "ABC",
    "skills": ["PROF1_EN, blah, test"]
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. Note that there exists the question [How can I convert a comma-separated string to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2858121/215552)

Comment: Do you mean `"skills": ["PROF1_EN", "blah", "test"]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string with commas to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272406/convert-string-with-commas-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const obj = {
  "action":"Profile Updates",
  "candidate_id":"1234",
  "docs_verified":"ABC",
  "skills":"PROF1_EN, blah, test"
  }

const output = JSON.stringify({...obj, skills: [obj.skills]});

console.log(output)
```

We don't know the context, but take it from here and massage it to your liking

Comment: imho - The question is an obvious dupe. Best to close as such rather than give dupe answers

Comment: @Kinglish This is up to moderator to check if it is a dupe, and if it is - provide a link to the original. Not my responsibility

Comment: that returns me this "{\&quot;action\&quot;:\&quot;Profile Updates\&quot;,\&quot;candidate_id\&quot;:\&quot;1234\&quot;,\&quot;docs_verified\&quot;:\&quot;ABC\&quot;,\&quot;skills\&quot;:[\&quot;PROF1_EN, blah, test\&quot;]}".

Comment: @Tim Oh well, I don't know how you are testing, but at least you know how to approach data massaging you need.

Comment: I think you meant `output={...obj, skills: [obj.skills]};`. OP doesn't need a string, they need a modified object ... also console.log can show objects just fine without stringify - and it's preferrable it view them without stringify b/c it shows structure

Comment: Then feel free to downvote it. I am not going an extra mile if the OP doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method to convert a string to an array based on a function

```
var obj = {
  "action":"Profile Updates",
  "candidate_id":"1234",
  "docs_verified":"ABC",
  "skills":"PROF1_EN, blah, test"
};
obj["skills"] = obj["skills"].split(" ");
```

Comment: this doesn't give the OP the correct answer, even if the OP corrects their expected result (which not likely their actual expected result) - this would make skills:`["PROF1_EN,", "blah,","test"]`