# Split string by comma, but ignore commas inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Example string:

```
"Foo","Bar, baz","Lorem","Ipsum"
```

Here we have **4** values in quotes separated by commas.

When I do this:

```
str.split(',').forEach(…
```

than that will also split the value `"Bar, baz"` which I don't want. Is it possible to ignore commas inside quotes with a regular expression?

Comment: Are your quotes correctly balanced? Can there be escaped quotes within quotes? (Don't you really need a CSV parser?)

Comment: Of course it is possible with a regular expression.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hm, I could go with a CSV parser, if I can load it via `<script>` onto my admin page. The CSV file is generated by PayPal, so I assume that it's syntactically valid.

Comment: Do you actually need the quotes in the result? From your example, it seems like commas are only present when separating quoted phrases or when separating words within the quoted phrases, so you should be able to do `str.slice(1,-1).split('","')` if it's consistent that way. If there can be spaces around the commas you're splitting on, then you can use a simpler regex `.split(/"\s*,\s*"/)`. And if you need the quotes, then `.map(function(item) { return '"' + item + '"'; })`

Comment: @cookiemonster Heh, that's a good idea :)

Answer (score 63):

One way would be using a **Positive Lookahead** assertion here.

```
var str = '"Foo","Bar, baz","Lorem","Ipsum"',
    res = str.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(res);  // [ '"Foo"', '"Bar, baz"', '"Lorem"', '"Ipsum"' ]
```

Regular expression:

```
,               ','
(?=             look ahead to see if there is:
(?:             group, but do not capture (0 or more times):
(?:             group, but do not capture (2 times):
 [^"]*          any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
 "              '"'
){2}            end of grouping
)*              end of grouping
 [^"]*          any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
$               before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)               end of look-ahead
```

Or a **Negative Lookahead**

```
var str = '"Foo","Bar, baz","Lorem","Ipsum"',
    res = str.split(/,(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

console.log(res); // [ '"Foo"', '"Bar, baz"', '"Lorem"', '"Ipsum"' ]
```

Comment: Here's my attempt in allowing single quotes too! `str.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^'"]*(?:'|")){2})*[^'"]*$)/)` Let me know if there are bugs. Need to have it correct too!

Comment: @hwnd, you sir are a regex wizard, this should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: Fixed some issues (such as not including the quotes) in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121244/2771889