# A RegEx to split by semicolon outside single or double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript RegEx to split a string by semicolon outside **single** or **double** quotes.

Actually i'm using the following regex `/(?!\B['"][^'"]*);(?![^'"]*['"]\B)/gm` that sadly doesn't cover every case.

What i need:

```js
const string = `Lorem ipsum; "dolor sit; amet"; consectetur 'adipiscing; elit.' Fusce; sit amet ligula.; Phasellus in laoreet quam.`;

const resultArr = string.split(/THEREGEX/gm);

console.log(resultArr);
// ["Lorem ipsum", "\"dolor sit; amet\"", " consectetur 'adipiscing; elit.' Fusce", "sit amet ligula.", " Phasellus in laoreet quam."]
```

Comment: I suggest not using a regex and just doing it with a loop with a stack to keep track of quotes.

Comment: I have reopened because you mentioned single or double quotes. Similar questions: [Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18893390) and [Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11456850) and [Split string by comma, but ignore commas inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23582276)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
((?:[^;'"]*(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'])*')[^;'"]*)+)|;
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LxDDM8/2)

**Code:**

```js
const s = `Lorem ipsum; "dolor sit; amet"; consectetur 'adipiscing; elit.' Fusce; sit amet ligula.; Phasellus in laoreet quam.`
const re = /((?:[^;'"]*(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|'(?:\\.|[^'])*')[^;'"]*)+)|;/

console.log( s.split(re).filter(Boolean) )
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `[^;'"]*`: Match 0 or more any character that are not `'` and `"` and not `;`
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `"(?:\\.|[^"])*"`: Match a double quoted substring ignoring all escaped quotes
    - `|`: OR
    - `'(?:\\.|[^'])*'`: Match a single quoted substring ignoring all escaped quotes
  - `)`: End non-capture group
  - `[^;'"]*`: Match 0 or more any character that are not `'` and `"` and not `;`
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `|`: OR
- `;`: Match a `;`
- `.filter(Boolean)`: is used to remove empty results from split array

Comment: Great pattern ++