# cli input parsing for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to make a CLIish server in node.js.
but I need a way to parse a string and run a function from an object.
what I mean is... I don't want to nest a million switch statements just to have the commands I need.
using 2 other StackOverflow answers, I got 1 part done. inputs.

now i just need to figure out how to figure ou where the command stops and the input begins.
example:

inputting `do say user:Yimmee msg:"well hello" "something random":yes`
I need to separate `do say` and the inputs.
this is what i started with, but I do not know how to finish it.

```
function command(command, usable){
  //usable is the object holding the commands that can be used.
  //here I set commandMain to the part of command that is the command
  /*and where commandInput is too. and I'm not forcing you,
  but is preferably to be converted to an object.*/
  var commandSplit = [];
  do{
    var match = (/[^ "]+|"([^"]*)"/gim).exec(commandMain);
    if(match != null){
      commandSplit.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[0]);
    }
  }while (match != null);
  var reach = `usable`;
  commandSplit.forEach((to, nu)=>{
    if(nu === commandSplit.length - 1){
      reach += `["_${to}"]`;
    }else{
      reach += `["${to}"]`;
    }
  });
  console.log(reach);
  try{
    return eval(reach)(commandInputs);
  }catch(error){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note I gave up a little, there will be some ridiculous errors.

big fat edit::::::::::::::::::::::L:::::::
idk how in the world process.argv works, and looking in one of the answers, i know how to set it.
but i am using a live websocket for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is an exercise, I'd strongly recommend not to implement your own command and argument parser. Use one of the existing libraries. A quick web search for "node cli library" yields a lot of results, including comparisons.

The libraries range from tiny and simple like [`minimist`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist), very popular ones like [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) or [`commander`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander), to heavier ones like [`oclif`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oclif).

I'd also recommend checking the [Command-line utilities section](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs#command-line-utilities) of Sindre Sorhus' Awesome Node.js list.

Comment: it's an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is passing options and arguments to a program. You can use `process.argv` to get these.

It's always good to have useful error messages and command line documentation. Hence, if you're distributing to users, a more robust library for this purpose is worth an extra dependency. Widely used is `yargs`, see their website at https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs for some examples.

If you want to do it using the basic `process.argv`, here's a solution:

This is your command in a format most people are used to: `node some.js --user Yimmee --msg "well hello" --random`

And the implementation

```js
let arguments = process.argv.slice(2); // this removes `node` and the filename from arguments list
console.log(arguments)
switch (arguments[0]) { // check that `say` is the first "command"
    case 'say':
        let options = process.argv.slice(3); // get the stuff after `say`
        let optionsObject = {} // key-value representation
        if (options.indexOf("--user") != -1) { // if it exists
            optionsObject.user = options[options.indexOf("--user")+1]
        }
        else {
            // you can throw an error here
        }
        if (options.indexOf("--msg") != -1) { // if it exists
            optionsObject.msg = options[options.indexOf("--msg")+1]
        }
        if (options.indexOf("--random") != -1) { // if it exists
            optionsObject.random = true
        }
        console.log(optionsObject) // you can use optionsObject for your program
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Invalid command");
}
```

EDIT: If this is happening inside the code as a function call, you can adapt above code:

```js
function test(argsString) {
    let arguments = argsString.split(/ (?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/); // split the string into an array at the spaces
    // ^ regex from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582276/
    console.log(arguments)
    switch (arguments[0]) { // check that `say` is the first "command"
        case 'say':
            let options = arguments.slice(1); // get the stuff after `say`
            let optionsObject = {} // key-value representation
            if (options.indexOf("--user") != -1) { // if it exists
                optionsObject.user = options[options.indexOf("--user") + 1]
            }
            else {
                // you can throw an error here
            }
            if (options.indexOf("--msg") != -1) { // if it exists
                optionsObject.msg = options[options.indexOf("--msg") + 1]
            }
            if (options.indexOf("--random") != -1) { // if it exists
                optionsObject.random = true
            }
            console.log(optionsObject) // you can use optionsObject for your program
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Invalid command");
    }
}
```

Comment: For more info about the standard options format, see here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70357/command-line-options-style-posix-or-what

Comment: @Yimmee I updated the answer with a function version