# Split spaces avoiding double-quoted JS strings : from 'a "b \\" c" d ' to ['a','"b \\" c"','d']

Tags: javascript, regex, json, command, command-line-arguments

I am currently building a small text editor for a custom file format. I have a GUI, but I also implemented a small output console. What I want to achieve is to add a very basic input field to execute some commands and pass parameters.
A command would look like :

`compile test.json output.bin -location "Paris, France" -author "Charles \"Demurgos\""`

My problem is to get an array containing the space-separated arguments, but preserving the double quoted parts which might be a string generated by `JSON.stringify` containing escaped double-quotes inside.

To be clear, the expected array for the previous command is :

```
[
    'compile',
    'test.json',
    'output.bin',
    '-location',
    '"Paris, France"',
    '-author',
    '"Charles \\"Demurgos\\""'
]
```

Then I can iterate over this array and apply a `JSON.parse` if `indexOf('"') == 0` to get the final result :

```
[
    'compile',
    'test.json',
    'output.bin',
    '-location',
    'Paris, France',
    '-author',
    'Charles "Demurgos"'
]
```

Thanks to this question : [Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript) . I was able to get what I need if the arguments do NOT contain any double-quotes. Here is the regex i got :

`/(".*?"|[^"\s]+)(?=\s*|\s*$)/g`

But it exits the current parameter when it encounters a double-quote, even if it is escaped. How can I adapt this RegEx to take care about the escaped or not double quotes ? And what about edge cases if I prompt `action "windowsDirectory\\" otherArg`, here the backslash is already escaped so even if it's followed by a double quote, it should exit the argument.
This a problem I was trying to avoid as long as possible during previous projects, but I feel it's time for me to learn how to properly take under-account escape characters.

Here is a JS-Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GwY8Y/1/
You can see that the beginning is well-parsed but the last arguments is split and bugs.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will give you the strings you need (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tM2tB3)):

```
"(?:\\"|\\\\|[^"])*"|\S+
```

Use it like this:

```
your_array = subject.match(/"(?:\\"|\\\\|[^"])*"|\S+/g);
```

**Explain Regex**

```
"                        # '"'
(?:                      # group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible)):
  \\                     #   '\'
  "                      #   '"'
 |                       #  OR
  \\\\                   #   two backslashes
 |                       #  OR
  [^"]                   #   any character except: '"'
)*                       # end of grouping
"                        # '"'
|                        # OR
\S+                      # non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                         # and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                         # most amount possible))
```

Comment: @Demurgos Hey Demurgos, did this help with your question? Or are you still wrestling with it? Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: Sorry, I had a weird bug this morning and could only access stack-overflow trough a proxy. First of all : thank you, it works fine... but fails on the last case I discuss in the last paragraph : if the string ends with an odd number of anti-slashes, then they are escaping themselves and the double-quote should be an END double quote, but here it ignores that because of the escaped anti-slash. I'm trying to fix it with http://tinyurl.com/p2k32ty but it fails without "lookbehind" in JS. Here is the buggy string : http://regex101.com/r/dG5yE6

Comment: @Demurgos Ha, a new case. :) I edited the answer (see new [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cA7kY1)) Pls let me know if that works for you. :)

Comment: I tried a few other cases, and it worked ! Thank you =) (I still have to train on regexp, but it was a general issue I had so I feel I will be able to extend it for my future needs)

Comment: @Demurgos Btw for a general solution to exclude certain situations from a regex, I highly recommend you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/match-or-replace-a-pattern-except-in-situations-s1-s2-s3-etc/23589204#23589204) or save it for later, I had a lot of fun writing the answer. :) Here we didn't use this technique as there was no need.

Comment: @Demurgos Terrific. Hanging up now, catch you some other time. :)