# PHP Split string with exception

Tags: php, split

I have a string that need to be split out :

```
3,1,'2015,05,14,11,18,0', 99
```

I want to split it into

```
3
1
'2015,05,14,11,18,0'
99
```

How could I do this with PHP ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript  You would  just need to replace the " with '

Comment: Did you try something or are you waiting us to write the code ... ?

Comment: I tried with explode the "," but it doesn't work because of '2015,05,14,11,18,0'

Comment: Hint: Use csv parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments (@tuananh in particular) said `csv parser`, so a little bit of trial, `fgetcsv` will work too, you'll just got to have that temporary file that holds the simple string, just unlink it after the operation.

Just set the enclosure to single quotes so that when the parser breaks it up, it gets the whole string enclosed with single quotes.

```
$string = "3,1,'2015,05,14,11,18,0', 99";
file_put_contents('temp.csv', $string); // create temporary file
$fh = fopen('temp.csv', 'r'); // open
$line = fgetcsv($fh, strlen($string) + 1, ',', "'"); // set enclosure to single quotes
fclose($fh);
unlink('temp.csv'); // remove temp file
print_r($line); // Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 2015,05,14,11,18,0 [3] => 99 )
// echo implode("\n", $line);
```

Sidenote: If this is indeed a csv file, then just use `fgetcsv` for the whole thing.

EDIT: As @deceze said about *use the csv function for strings*

There's this thing called `str_getcsv`, so no need to actually put it inside a file the unlink it whatsoever.

```
$string = "3,1,'2015,05,14,11,18,0', 99";
$line = str_getcsv($string, ',', "'"); // set enclosure to single quotes
print_r($line);
```

Comment: You could use an in-memory buffer instead of a physical file; or use the csv function for strings. This is needlessly complicated either way.

Comment: @deceze lol :D there is that `str_getcsv` i forgot about it, thanks for the reminder