# Javascript: Split Comma Delimited Quoted Strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have a single string, which is itself a comma delimited list of quoted strings - which can have commas within them.

Example:

```
var str = '"long one","short","oh, look","wow.", ""';
```

I need to split this into an array:

```
['long one', 'short', 'oh, look', 'wow.', '']

// will take this if it is easier
['"long one"', '"short"', '"oh, look"', '"wow."', '""']
```

I tried splitting by `,` but it throws off entries with a comma in them. I also tried splitting by `\",`, but it creates lob-sided string:

```
['"long one', '"short', '"oh, look', '"wow.', '"']
```

I tried splitting by `\",\"` but causes the same issue but just for the first and last entry:

```
['"long one', 'short', 'oh, look', 'wow.', '"']
```

I also tried the regex expression found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript), but it adds an empty entry at the start and end of the array:

```
['', '"long one"', '"short"', '"oh, look"', '"wow."', '""', '']
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the regex you found then remove the first and last elements?

Comment: Match [`"(.*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/hP4kG9/1)

Comment: Do these come from a csv file?

Comment: yes, they do come from a CSV file. @MikeC, you're right, I could do that. I suppose I just didn't want to risk lobbing of some data - on the off chance the extra entries were not attached

Comment: Since quotes don't appear in quoted strings, and your data is delimited by quotes, it's really as simple as finding all `"([^"]*)"`. This is the simplest solution. If you later add caveats to this simple description, a fuller regex is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could treat it as part of a JSON string and append the necessary parts for parsing as array.

```js
var string ='"long one","short","oh, look","wow.", ""',
    array = JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');
console.log(array);
```

Comment: With the caveat that any special characters are in there the same as they are in JSON - tabs, line breaks, etc. For example, if double-quotes are escaped as double-double quotes instead of `\"`, then this won't work.

Comment: right, that would be a problem, but it does not look like this in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Joe. I think this solution works just fine for my case though.

Comment: Yep, it's a very good solution. Just always good to keep the edge cases in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.split()` comma `,` characters if comma is followed by double-quote `"` character using `RegExp` `/,(?=")/`

```
str.split(/,(?=")/)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = '"long one","short","oh, look","wow.", ""';
var answer = s.split(/("*,.?")/gi).filter(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/"/g, '').length > 2
}).map(function (a) {
  return a.replace(/"/g, '')
});
console.log(s);
console.log(answer);
```