# node js, how to parse strings like this?

Tags: javascript

I want to parse the following strings

> 3693,"Toxic Avenger, The (1985)",Comedy|Horror

to

> 3693,
>   "Toxic Avenger, The (1985)",
>   Comedy|Horror.

similarly, the following

> 161944,The Last Brickmaker in America (2001),Drama

should be parsed to

> 161944
>
> The Last Brickmaker in America (2001)
>
> Drama

I can't do it by splitting by comma, since there is a comma within " , ".

The worked solution:
LS05 suggested me to use "substring", so I did it and it worked perfect.
here it is.

```
    var pos1 = line.indexOf(',');
    var line = line.substring(pos1+1); 

    pos1 = line.indexOf(',');
    pos2 = line.lastIndexOf(',');

    let movie_id = line.substring(0,pos1);
    let movie_tag = line.substring(pos1+1,pos2);
    let movie_timespan = line.substring(pos2+1);
```

Thanks to LS05  :)

Comment: What type of data is this ?

Comment: Maybe you can substring the first and the last part, so titles will remain

Comment: @alim oh ok, I've based my comment on your example data :)

Comment: @LS05 actually your idea turned out to be the best, worked great. thanks!  :)

Comment: @alim Good! Maybe you can show up the code (or the part that uses this strategy) just for reference on your process to the solution :)

Comment: Put the solution after the question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex to parse your string which will exclude commas which are inside quotes

```
var str = '3693,"Toxic Avenger, The (1985)",Comedy|Horror';
console.log(str.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g).join("\n"));
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cc38s1a6/) (Refer to credits if you want to know how the above regex works)

As far as the code goes, I try to split your string ignoring the commas which are inside the string, and later we join the array items again using a new line character `\n`

<sup>[Credits for Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457952/1542290)</sup>

Comment: This removes `,` at the end of line. `join(",\n")` may help

Comment: it has a problem. can't parse this string '161944,The Last Brickmaker in America (2001),Drama'.  removed the strings if there are no  " ".

Comment: I added one more example. could you check it out please!

Comment: @alim You need to tweak your regex - https://jsfiddle.net/cc38s1a6/1/ example, but you need to tweak that so it works with any types of quotes

Comment: @alim Try this `console.log(str.match(/(["'].*?["']|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g).join("\n"));` (not 100% sure though if it might break something else), this will accept single and double quoted strings

Answer (score 3):

You could use a CSV parser such as [`papa parse`](http://papaparse.com/) or if you feel that a third party library is not needed you may take a look at [`this function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/29407).