# splitting text in csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a csv file with sample data like this

```
153,"Doe, John","","RBG","",10,"","","10/15/2017","Sunday","RESTDAY"," ",10,"","","","","","",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,"",0.00,0.00,""
```

When I split it using the split() function in javascript like this. `csvdata.split(",")` it works well but I encountered a problem when the fullname is separated with comma like "Doe, John". Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a different delimiter to separate names then

Comment: Someone did it here with regex:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457952/1306026

Comment: Well that's only a useful suggestion if OP has the power to change the source...

Comment: the csv file I used was an output of another system so it is impossible for me to  change the format of names

Comment: oh @JoshuaRubin thank you. It is there, I'm trying to search for hours. Thank you again :)