# Split string with custom condition in javascript (Not Duplicate)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have following string :

```
var str = '15156,"ABALONE, FRIED",60.1,189,19.63,,,,';
```

i want to split it in the following way :-

```
[15156, "ABALONE, FRIED", 60.1, 189, 19.63, null, null, null]
```

i have try this:-

```
var strArray = str.split(",");
output:- 
[15156, "ABALONE", "FRIED", 60.1, 189, 19.63]
```

How can i get this using javascript's split function or any other way.

Comment: Googled and found this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript

Comment: You could use `JSON.parse('[' + str + ']')`

Comment: It gives error for '15156,"ABALONE, FRIED",60.1,189,19.63,,,,'

Comment: Food.insertFoodDatabase = function(data, cb) {
    fs.readFile('client/foodDB.csv',{encoding:'utf8'},function(err, data){
      if(err) return cb(err);
      data = data.split('\r\n');
      _.map(data,function(v,key){
        v= v.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
        console.log(v);
        console.log("-----------------------------------------");
      })   
    });
  };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert that into array like string representation and you can parse it to get the desired output:

```js
var str = '15156,"ABALONE, FRIED",60.1,189,19.63';
var res = JSON.parse('[' + str + ']')
console.log(res);
```

Comment: var str = '15156,"ABALONE, FRIED",60.1,189,19.63,,,,';  For this it gives error