# Regex to extract string between commas but including quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
const splitRegex = new RegExp('(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\\s*,|\\s*$)', 'g');
const row = line.match(splitRegex);
```

to extract strings in quotes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript/57121244#57121244) but ignoring commas, however, it doesn't work with string like: `6000.1, Basic "Internet" abc, 101, NO_VLAN` which will return just [`"6000.1", "abc", "101", "NO_VLAN"`]

I tried adding regex for "a word followed by a space" `([^\s]*)(?=\s*)` at the beginning and the end of the original one but it looks even worse...  `[ "6000.1,", "\"Internet\" abc,", " 101,", " NO_VLAN" ]`

What I would like is  [`"6000.1", "Basic \"Internet\" abc", "101", "NO_VLAN"`] or [`"6000.1", "Basic \"Internet\"", "101", "NO_VLAN"`] if the string is `6000.1, Basic "Internet", 101, NO_VLAN`

Thank you.

Comment: Try `s.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|[^",])+/g)`

Comment: Why does including the ?: work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
text.match(/(?=\S)(?:"[^"]*"|[^",])+/g)
```

Or, if you need to include escape sequences:

```
text.match(/(?=\S)(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|[^",])+/g)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/1XtgU2/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/1XtgU2/2).

**Details**

- `(?=\S)` - next char must be a non-whitespace char
- `(?:"[^"]*"|[^",])+`  - one or more occurrences (`+`) of the pattern sequence defined in a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) (`(?:...)`):

  - `"[^"]*"` - either `"`, then 0 or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^",]` - any char other than `"` and `,`.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = String.raw`6000.1, Basic "Internet \"text\"" abc, 101, NO_VLAN`;
console.log(text.match(/(?=\S)(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|[^",])+/g));
```

Comment: Thank you! For the 1st one, why can't it be `(?:\S"[^"]*"|[^",])+` ?

Comment: @user545871 It would require a non-whitespace char and then a double quote substring in the first alternative, it will overmatch, or undermatch.  We only want the first char of a match to be a non-whitespace char in order to avoid trimming the results later.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works with your example `((?=\S)[^,]+)`:

```js
const regex = /((?=\S)[^,]+)/gm;
const str = `6000.1, Basic "Internet" abc, 101, NO_VLAN`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```