# Split string into array by space, but keeping phrases between quotes (including spaces) as a whole element

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Examples:

```js
test "testing 123! :)" // -> ['test', 'testing 123! :)']

test "\"testing these are some nice quotes!\"" // -> ['test', '"testing these are some nice quotes!\"']
```

Is there anyway to do this with regex in JavaScript? Perhaps it could also work with --flag=value as well!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript). Just need to cusomize the REGEX.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
const exemple = `testA testB "testC testD  " testE `
const textArray = exemple
  .split(new RegExp(`("[\\s\\S]*")`, 'g'))
  .flatMap(text => text.match(`"`) ? text : text.split(`\\s+`))
```

[Exemple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY97B.png)