# Regarding perl 5.8.3 DBI installation

Tags: perl, activeperl

Noticed our system has perl 5.8.3.  I am unable to locate the DBI.pm.    When i did     perl -V it was showing the below output. Pasted it below.  Using HPUX11 os. All installed files under the perl installation directory are having root or bin as owner of the file.  I dont have root password now.   I want to install DBI.pm.  how can i do it.  Do i need to download it from CPAN or Active Perl Website?

perl -V

> Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):   Compile-time options:
>   MULTIPLICITY USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
>   Locally applied patches:
>           ActivePerl Build 809
>           22218 Remove the caveat about detached threads crashing on Windows
>           22201 Avoid threads+win32 crash by freeing Perl interpreter slightly later
>           22169 Display 'out of memeory' errors using low-level I/O
>           22159 Upgrade to Time::Hires 1.55
>           22120 Make 'Configure -Dcf_by=...' work
>           22051 Upgrade to Time::HiRes 1.54
>           21540 Fix backward-compatibility issues in if.pm   Built under hpux   Compiled at May 17 2005 18:12:56
>
> ```
> /opt/perl/lib/5.8.3/PA-RISC1.1-thread-multi
> /opt/perl/lib/5.8.3
> /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/PA-RISC1.1-thread-multi
> /opt/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.3
> /opt/perl/lib/site_perl
> ```

All installed files under the perl installation directory are having root or bin as user id.  I dont have root password now.   I want to install DBI. How can i do it?

Comment: You need root/sudo access as far as I know.

Comment: @Dondi Michael Stroma - [that is not true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPAN has an option `local::lib` which will install to `~/perl5`. If that works for you, that's your best option, otherwise create a directory somewhere that you do have access (probably under your /home), download DBI.pm (and any dependencies) manually, and put it in there.

Then add the directory name to your PERLLIB environment variable (which is not set at the moment). Do `perl -V` to confirm that `~/perl5` has been added to `@INC`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does the DBI.pm works for all the perl versions? How can i easily identiy which perl version a module works?

Comment: I think cpan would check that, but I don't know that for sure. I did find this statement in the change history (dbi.perl.org) for Jan/2012: "NOTE: The officially supported minimum perl version will change from perl 5.8.1 (2003) to perl 5.8.3 (2004) in a future release.", so you should be OK. You will also need to have drivers for whichever database you want to connect to.