# Web-crawler optimization

Tags: perl, optimization, search-engine, web-crawler

I am building a basic search engine using vector-space model and this is the crawler for returning 500 URLs and removes the SGML tags from the content. However, it is very slow (takes more than 30mins for retrieving the URLs only). How can I optimize the code? I have inserted wikipedia.org as an example starting URL.

```
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Response;
use HTML::LinkExtor;

my $starting_url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page';
my @urls = $starting_url;
my %alreadyvisited;
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$browser->timeout(5);
my $url_count = 0;

while (@urls) 
{ 
     my $url = shift @urls;
     next if $alreadyvisited{$url}; ## check if already visited

     my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
     my $response = $browser->request($request);

     if ($response->is_error())
     {
         print $response->status_line, "\n"; ## check for bad URL
     }
     my $contents = $response->content(); ## get contents from URL
     push @c, $contents;
     my @text = &RemoveSGMLtags(\@c);
     #print "@text\n";

     $alreadyvisited{$url} = 1; ## store URL in hash for future reference
     $url_count++;
     print "$url\n";

     if ($url_count == 500) ## exit if number of crawled pages exceed limit
     {
         exit 0; 
     } 


     my ($page_parser) = HTML::LinkExtor->new(undef, $url); 
     $page_parser->parse($contents)->eof; ## parse page contents
     my @links = $page_parser->links; 

     foreach my $link (@links) 
     {
             $test = $$link[2];
             $test =~ s!^https?://(?:www\.)?!!i;
             $test =~ s!/.*!!;
             $test =~ s/[\?\#\:].*//;
             if ($test eq "en.wikipedia.org")  ## check if URL belongs to unt domain
             {
                 next if ($$link[2] =~ m/^mailto/); 
                 next if ($$link[2] =~ m/s?html?|xml|asp|pl|css|jpg|gif|pdf|png|jpeg/);
                 push @urls, $$link[2];
             }
     }
     sleep 1;
}


sub RemoveSGMLtags 
{
    my ($input) = @_;
    my @INPUTFILEcontent = @$input;
    my $j;my @raw_text;
    for ($j=0; $j<$#INPUTFILEcontent; $j++)
    {
        my $INPUTFILEvalue = $INPUTFILEcontent[$j];
        use HTML::Parse;
        use HTML::FormatText;
        my $plain_text = HTML::FormatText->new->format(parse_html($INPUTFILEvalue));
        push @raw_text, ($plain_text);
    }
    return @raw_text;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to perl and still learning how to write an efficient code.

Comment: You are trying to download the *entirety* of `en.wikipedia.org`. Apart from the likelihood that Wikipedia wouldn't like this at all, it would be something of an achievement if you could achieve that in under 30 minutes. Please think twice about doing things like this, and carefully examine the terms of service of any site you do it to. Most will not want their data abused like this.

Comment: Actually, I have to crawl my university website. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I put this URL just as an example.

Answer (score 5):

- *Always* `use strict`
- *Never* use the ampersand `&` on subroutine calls
- Use [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) to manipulate URLs

You have a `sleep 1` in there, which I assume is to avoid hammering the site too much, which is good. But the bottleneck in almost any web-based application is the internet itself, and you won't be able to make your program any faster without requesting more from the site. That means removing your `sleep` and perhaps making parallel requests to the server using, for instance, [`LWP::Parallel::RobotUA`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::Parallel::RobotUA). Is that a way you should be going?

Comment: Thanks, the code is much faster when I remove the sleep. Will try using parallel requests.

Comment: Another significant issue, probably, you'd know if you had profiled the code, is that you're calling HTML::FormatText->new->format(parse_html( on every line of input when you could instead call it once per entire webpage.

Answer (score 3):

Use WWW::Mechanize which handles all the URL parsing and extraction for you.  So much easier than all the link parsing you're dealing with.  It was created specifically for the sort of thing you're doing, and it's a subclass of LWP::UserAgent so you should just be able to change all your LWP::UserAgent to WWW::Mechanize without having to change any code, except for all the link extraction, so you can do this:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( 'someurl.com' );
my @links = $mech->links;
```

and then `@links` is an array of WWW::Mechanize::Link objects.

Comment: thanks but I cannot use Mechanize since I have to execute the final code in a server in which that package is absent and I do not have the  permission to install it

Comment: @user2154731: Learn how to [install Perl modules under your own home directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions). You'll find it useful for far more than just WWW::Mechanize.