# searching a directory using Findstr in perl

Tags: windows, perl, findstr

I want to look for a string in all the files in a directory in perl. But the following code is not working

```
if ($^O eq "MSWin32") {
my @results = `findstr /s "Hello" /d:\\Testing`;
print "my results \n @results\n";
#or 
system('findstr /s "Hello" /d:\\Testing');
}
```

I am running the script from "C:" and it contains "Testing" directory. 
For the non windows system it works perfectly fine using grep system command. 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use an external utility? [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/lib/File/Find.pm) and other core perl functions seems better.

Comment: So according to the "Find" documentation, I can execute a function on each file in the directory tree. But after that how can I look for a pattern in one file w/o opening it? I need to use grep command for that anyway. Am I right? I am sorry I am not very much familiar with Find command.

Comment: @chrsblck That would entail either loading each found file into memory, or still needing to call an external utility.

Comment: @AaronMiller I don't follow. `File::Find`'s purpose is to "Traverse a directory tree". Or are you saying opening each file and `grep`ing the lines is going to be too memory intensive? Which I don't think is true, if you do it the right way. To be clear. `while(my $line = <$fh> )` does NOT load the whole file into memory

Comment: @user1549994 Yes, you would then need to open the file. Unless you have a very good reason, I would avoid `shell`ing out.

Comment: @chrsblck An excellent point, which I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *not* using **findstr** correctly.

1. The order matters: switches/options should come before the argument (search string) (see output of `findstr /?`)
2. The argument which specifies which file(s) to search is a **required** argument (this argument allows wildcard characters).

With all those in mind, a working **findstr** command would be

```
findstr /s /d:"Testing" *
```

If you just need the filenames containing matches (not the content of line in the file with the match), use the `/m` switch

```
findstr /s /m /d:"Testing" *
```

Also the `/s` switch is not needed if you don't need recursive searching (e.g. search the subdirectory of **C:\Testing**)

Another thing to note is that if you use `/d:"Testing"`, the first line of the output would be

```
Testing:
```

which would end up as the first element in your array. To counter this, you can `shift` your array, or better still, change the working directory to **Testing** in Perl.

The code snippet below shows how I would rewrite this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if ($^O eq "MSWin32") {
    chdir("Testing");
    my @results = qx'findstr /s /m "Hello" *';
    local $" = ", ";
    @results = map { s/^/Testing\\/; chomp; $_ } @results;
    chdir("..");
    print "my results \n@results\n";
}
```

Other notes (god, this post is too long already!):

- `qx'...'` is somewhat equivalent to `` `...` `` except that whatever is in between is not interpolated.
- `$"` is the separator used for array elements when the array is interpolated within double quotes in a `print` or `say` (once you get the code working, change its value to see what it does)
- The `map` does some processing on each element of the array

  - `s/^/Testing\\/` prefixes each filename with "**Testing**" (so that your results will be **relative to C:** instead of relative to Testing)
  - `chomp` removes trailing whitespace character (e.g. newline) from the result
  - The last `$_` makes sure that it returns the modified filename (instead of the return value of `s///` which is # substitution)

You can go one step further and parameterize the folder name ("**Testing**") and string-to-search in the code, and even get user input for those parameters. But that is left as an exercise to the reader (because I'm le tired and the post is already too long)

Comment: There's no such thing as "too long" when it comes to informative answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try http://search.cpan.org/~mneylon/File-Grep-0.02/Grep.pm

Also, when writing functions cross platform for Linux and Windows, I tend to include this at the top of my scripts just to cover anything I may do that is windows specific:

```
BEGIN { # include additional Win32 specific modules when running on MS platforms
  if ($^O =~ /Win32/) {
    require Win32::AdminMisc; import Win32::AdminMisc;
    require Win32::API; import Win32::API;
    require Win32::GUI; import Win32::GUI;
    $wincon=Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow();
  }
}

# your code starts here
```

Comment: Because of some limitations I can not use CPAN library functions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [the `findstr` documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true), you appear to have your `findstr` options a bit mixed up; `/d` doesn't take an argument, and it looks like switches are required to appear before the search string and the start path. So try this:

```
findstr /d /s "Hello" \\Testing
```

in place of the `findstr` command you're currently using, and you may find better results.

Comment: I get this output with what you suggested                   :
"    FINDSTR: /d ignored"

Comment: Whoops, yeah, the `/d` switch there is superfluous, `/s` suffices to tell findstr to recurse into the directory tree. `/d` would be useful if you needed to pass multiple directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /s "Hello" /d:\\Testing
```

specifies a UNC path, i.e., looking for files on a remote host named `Testing`. Use a single backslash to specify a directory. But I'm not sure that that's what you want either

```
findstr /s "Hello" /d:\Testing
```

specifies the directory `Testing` at the root of the current drive, which is to say `C:\Testing`. If you want to specify the directory `Testing` under the *current* directory, then it's

```
findstr /s "Hello" /d:Testing
```

and if you're also finding `findstr` to be pretty tempermental, you may have better luck with something like

```
findstr /s "Hello" /d:Testing\*
```

But of course, the **real** solution is to install the DWIM tool [`ack`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::Ack), your [inability to use CPAN libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/251705/168657) notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Your invocation of `findstr` is hanging because you did not provide a glob pattern to match against.

Consider using code similar to

```
if ($^O eq "MSWin32") {
  my @results = `findstr /s /p /d:C:\\Testing "Hello" *.*`;
  die "$0: findstr failed" if $?;

  if (@results) {
    print @results;
  }
  else {
    warn "$0: no results\n";
  }
}
```

Notes:

- The big change is the addition of `*.*` at the end of the command.
- Check that `findstr` ran successfully by examining `$?` rather than blindly assuming success.
- The `/p` option tells `findstr` to skip files with unprintable characters. You may or may not want to retain this option.