# Regex Add More Groups and Efficiency Perl

Tags: regex, perl

So I am going to preface this by saying I came up with this using [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and just typing in random thing until I got what I needed.

The goal I had in mind was to generate an array from a json string using.

```
my @valuesArray=$msgPayload=~/((?=["]).+?(?=["])")/g;
```

This works for most cases, however it just selects values from one quote to the next quote. this becomes an issue when there is a value like true, false, or null.

Example String

```
..."email":"","lastLogon":null,"pwdChanged":"0","status":"A","phoneNumber":"","extension":"","locale":"en_US","boChecked":false,"boUserId":"","UserId":"TWEH","sChecked":false,...
```

So I am working around this by using multiple replaces before actually splitting up into an array.

```
$msgPayload =~ s/:true/:"true"/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:false/:"false"/g;
$msgPayload =~ s/:null/:"null"/g;
my @valuesArray=$msgPayload=~/((?=["]).+?(?=["])")/g;
```

Now I was wondering if there was a way to combine all of this into a single regex expresion where it can also select the true false and null values without first having to do the replace. And if it is possible I feel like it would be more efficient doing it that way, but if I wrong, I would love to know more.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
We don't have any modules installed, and I doubt I could get any installed for this project since it is so small. I am just trying to make due with what I have.

The data is stored in a varchar column in a table. One full example would be received like so.

```
[ {  &quot;signonId&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;userId&quot; : &quot;USERNAME&quot;,  &quot;groupID&quot; : &quot;Master&quot;,  &quot;userName&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;phoneNumber&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;extension&quot; : &quot;4444&quot;,  &quot;emailAddress&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;password&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;locale&quot; : &quot;&quot;}, {  &quot;signonId&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;userId&quot; : &quot;USERNAME&quot;,  &quot;groupID&quot; : &quot;Master&quot;,  &quot;userName&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;phoneNumber&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;extension&quot; : &quot;5555&quot;,  &quot;emailAddress&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;password&quot; : &quot;&quot;,  &quot;locale&quot; : &quot;&quot;} ]
```

Which then when you replace the " with " and format it, it becomes...

```
[
   {
      "signonId":"",
      "userId":"USERNAME",
      "groupID":"Master",
      "userName":"",
      "phoneNumber":"",
      "extension":"4444",
      "emailAddress":"",
      "password":"",
      "locale":""
   },
   {
      "signonId":"",
      "userId":"USERNAME",
      "groupID":"Master",
      "userName":"",
      "phoneNumber":"",
      "extension":"5555",
      "emailAddress":"",
      "password":"",
      "locale":""
   }
]
```

Comment: In general it is better to parse JSON using a dedicated parser module, see for example [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS). Then you can also easily extract your array values from the resulting hash.

Comment: If you give us some correct JSON, we can show you how to turn it into a data structure. Regular expressions cannot exhaustively parse JSON in the way you're trying to. But it's probably as simple as `my $data = JSON -> decode ( $string );` and go from there.

Comment: @Sobrique  We don't have any modules installed, and I doubt I could get any installed for this project since it is so small. I am just trying to make due with what I have.

Comment: perl-JSON ships by default with Centos/Redhat. Otherwise what you're trying to do is re-implement some prior art, with less testing.

Comment: In 2019, there is [no excuse for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735836/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-without-root-privileges) [not being able to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251705/how-can-i-use-a-new-perl-module-without-install-permissions) [install modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user).

Comment: @mob Thanks for the helpful information, this is my first time working with perl, so there is a lot I do not know.

Answer (score 5):

First, your example data looks like it wants to be a hash, not an array.

Second, parsing JSON with regexes is (as you have already discovered) very fragile and error-prone.  It's *much* better to use a proper JSON parser, such as the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON 'from_json';
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = q({
  "email": "",
  "lastLogon":null,
  "pwdChanged":"0"
} );

my $decoded = from_json( $json );

print Dumper $decoded;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'email' => '',
          'pwdChanged' => '0',
          'lastLogon' => undef
        };
```

Comment: the issue is we do not have any modules installed, and i doubt I could get someone to install them. It's just a weird set of circumstances, I get the string from a table where a json string is stored as a varchar. I've added more proper examples to my above question.

Comment: @MuamerBektić If you are on Perl 5.14 or newer, [JSON::PP](https://perldoc.pl/JSON::PP) is core (though slow). As an alternative, [JSON::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Tiny) can be [fatpacked](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) into any script.

Comment: @Grinnz I see [no JSON listed in perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-J.html).  Is that only about docs? (I seem to recall that it was added to core (v5.14?) ... and later removed ... false memory?)

Comment: @MuamerBektić  I absolutely second the idea to somehow use a module. The `JSON::Tiny` linked by Grinnz can even merely be copied -- it's a single file with no dependencies (from what I can see)

Comment: @zdim I'm probably going to try to incorporate it, the only issue is that the strings are aren't always json values, sometimes they show up as xml, and I didn't want to have to use two modules, so i was just planning on using arrays created by regex. My biggest concern is going to be efficiency in the end so if it does improve speed i will do it.

Comment: @MuamerBektić Hang on ... do you mean to say that you don't actually have proper JSON? If _any_ of it isn't correct JSON then modules will choke on it.  What do you mean by "_strings aren't always json values ... but show up as xml_" ?  Can you update the question to this fact, and give example(s) of string(s) you have which aren't valid JSON?

Comment: @zdim so basically, i am pulling these values from a table where they are being dumped. The values being dumped are one of three things, XML format, JSON string format, or Empty. I have an if statement set up to differentiate between these three situations, and proceed accordingly. So there's no way the JSONprocess would happen for an XML string. Sorry if I poorly worded it the first time.

Comment: @zdim perldoc.perl.org is unmaintained and has many [longstanding issues](https://github.com/jonallen/perldoc.perl.org/issues) (like the one where it has never listed HTTP::Tiny and JSON::PP that have been core since 5.14), this is why I created perldoc.pl in the first place.