# How do I send email to my Gmail account using SMTP and Perl?

Tags: perl, email, smtp, gmail

I don't want to use sendmail to send an email but would prefer to use SMTP. How can I use Perl to send an email to my GMAIL account?

Comment: I don't really get the question: Do you want to talk directly to Google's SMTP server? Or your own? Is there anything gmail-specific about this question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

personally I would suggest you to use my module [Email::Send::SMTP::TLS](http://search.cpan.org/~fayland/Email-Send-SMTP-TLS-0.03/lib/Email/Send/SMTP/TLS.pm)
which works pretty well through the TLS of Google Mail.

Thanks.

```
use Email::Send;

my $mailer = Email::Send->new( {
    mailer => 'SMTP::TLS',
    mailer_args => [
        Host => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        Port => 587,
        User => 'username@gmail.com',
        Password => 'password',
        Hello => 'fayland.org',
    ]
} );

use Email::Simple::Creator; # or other Email::
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => 'username@gmail.com',
        To      => 'to@mail.com',
        Subject => 'Subject title',
    ],
    body => 'Content.',
);

eval { $mailer->send($email) };
die "Error sending email: $@" if $@;
```

Answer (score 6):

As per the comment, it's not clear if you want to send email via Google's SMTP, or just send email in general (perhaps to your gmail account). You should check out [Email::Send](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Send) and possibly [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Send::Gmail).

Alternatively, if what you're really asking is how do I move email from somewhere that isn't Gmail to Gmail, I've had very good luck with IMAP using [Mail::Box](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::Box) and the [Mail::Box::IMAP4::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::Box::IMAP4::SSL) backend.  You can see an example of use [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DAGOLDEN/Mail-Box-IMAP4-SSL-0.02/examples/list-inbox.pl).

Comment: Email::Send has been recently deprecated in favor of Email::Sender

Answer (score 2):

I've always used and had very good luck with [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Sender/).

Answer (score 1):

There are muliple SMTP modules on CPAN, for example [Net::ESMTP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-ESMTP). Also, sendmail very probably does use SMTP to communicate with mail servers, so what's your real reason for not wanting to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility you might want to look at is using the [Email::Send::Gmail](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/Email-Send-Gmail-0.33/lib/Email/Send/Gmail.pm) module from CPAN.  This will allow you to send email from your Gmail account to any account (for example, to yourself)

Answer (score 1):

[Email::Send](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Send/lib/Email/Send.pm) (as used in Fayland Lam's answer) is deprecated:

> Email::Send is going away... well, not really going away, but it's
>   being officially marked "out of favor."

This works for me, using the preferred Email::Sender:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver = 'server';
my $smtpport = 587;
my $smtpuser   = 'username';
my $smtppassword = 'password';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  ssl => "starttls",
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'mymail@gmail.com',
    From    => 'sender@example.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org) (Comprehensive Perl Archive Network) I recommend you to bookmark that site. It contains third party (mostly well tested) libraries.

An example showing how to send emails using perl: http://www.perlfect.com/articles/sendmail.shtml

Comment: OP said: "I don't want to use sendmail"

Answer (score 0):

I happen to use [`MIME::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite/), which is a wrapper around `Net::SMTP` to simplify the process of building email objects, file attachments, and sending the payload.

If you're not familiar with installing modules, check:

On Windows, use the ActiveState Perl Package Manager (in start menu)

On Unix, use CPAN: `$ sudo cpan Module::Name`

On hosted Unix accounts: [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-to-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't like sendmail, another option is to use [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), another MTA.

Here are the instructions I followed to get it setup on my machine, using gmail:
http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/postfix_tutorial.html

This might be useful too, if you get a warning about failing to verify a certificate from Thawte Premium Server CA.
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-894355.html