# How do I make a hash with the output of kstat -p using Perl?

Tags: perl, sunos, kstat

I am working so some stuffs where I need to get some information using `kstat -p`. So I am thinking to create a hash variable with all output of `kstat -p`.

```
Sample output from kstat -p

cpu_stat:0:cpu_stat0:user       18804249
```

To access values

```
@{$kstat->{cpu_stat}{0}{cpu_stat0}}{qw(user)};
```

I have also looked at CPAN for any available module and found `Sun::Solaris::Kstat` but that is not available with my Sun version. Please suggest code to create a hash variable with output values in `kstat -p`.

Comment: Sun::Solaris::Kstat doesn't seem to exist. Solaris::Kstat does, though. Why don't you simply install that?

Comment: The data structure you are trying to create looks rather strange. You want an array at the top level? And what is qw(user) supposed to do?

Comment: Finally, what exactly is your problem? Do you need help parsing the output of kstat? Or do you need help creating that data stucture?

Comment: @Manni: 1) I don't have permissions to install any perl modules on this system.
2)yes and qw is to use other values like qw(user kernal iowait) 
3) I need help to create a data structure and to access values based on the options provided as given in my option to access values.

Comment: You don't need permission to install Perl modules. See, e.g., here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory

Comment: @Manni: I will do that if i can but Solaris::Kstat module in CPAN this only supports Solaris 2.5.1, 2.6 & 2.7 and I have version 5.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With references, creating a hierarchical data structure is only slightly tricky; the only interesting part comes from the fact that we want to handle the final level differently (assigning a value instead of creating a new hash level).

```
# If you don't create the ref here then assigning $target won't do
# anything useful later on.
my $kstat = {};
open my $fh, '-|', qw(kstat -p) or die "$! execing kstat";
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($compound_key, $value) = split " ", $_, 2;
  my @hier = split /:/, $compound_key;
  my $last_key = pop @hier; # handle this one differently.
  my $target = $kstat;
  for my $key (@hier) { # All intermediate levels
    # Drill down to the next level, creating it if we have to.
    $target = ($target->{$key} ||= {});
  }
  $target->{$last_key} = $value; # Then write the final value in place.
}
```