# How do I get the PID of the process I start with Perl's system()?

Tags: perl, system

I'm writing a Perl script that runs 4 simultaneous, identical processes with different input parameters (see background  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961682/using-perl-with-multiple-cores) - the rest of my question will make much more sense after reading that).

I am making a system() call to a program that generates data (XFOIL, again see above link). My single-core version of this program looks like this:

```
eval{
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub{die "TIMEOUT"};
    alarm 250;
    system("xfoil <command_list >xfoil_output");
    alarm 0;
};

if ($@){
    # read the output log and run timeout stuff...
    system('killall xfoil') # Kill the hung XFOIL. now it's a zombie.
}
```

Essentially, XFOIL should take only about 100 seconds to run - so after 250 seconds the program is hanging (presumably waiting for user input that it's never going to get).

The problem now is, if I do a killall in the multi-core version of my program, I'm going to kill 3 other instances of XFOIL, and those processes are generating data. So I need to kill only the hung instance, and this requires getting a PID.

I don't know very much about forks and such. From what I can tell so far, I would run an exec('xfoil') inside the child process that I fork. But the PID of the exec() will be different than the PID of the child process (or is it? It's a separate process so I'd assume it is, but again I've no experience with this..), so this still doesn't help when I want to forcefully kill the process since I won't have the PID anyway. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: "But the PID of the exec() will be different than the PID of the child process." Are you sure about this? `exec` keeps the same PID, unless Perl is doing something weird.

Comment: I was under the impression that since the exec() call spawns a new process, it would have a different PID? I've been searching forever and I haven't seen anything about whether it's the same PID as the fork()ed Perl child.. I must be mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: exec doesn't spawn a new process, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the PID, [fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) the process yourself instead of using [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). The `system` command is mostly designed as a "fire and forget" tool. If you want to interact with the process, use something else. See, for instance, the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation.

I think you've already looked at [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager) based on answers to your question [How can I make my Perl script use multiple cores for child processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961682/how-can-i-make-my-perl-script-use-multiple-cores-for-child-processes)

Comment: brian, thanks for the help. To be honest, I was making life more complicated than it had to be. I'm squared away now - but thanks for insight into exec() vs system(), etc.