# Local cpan builds

Tags: perl, installation, cpan, home-directory

I'd like to use a home directory specific, non-root directory for stuff I install from cpan. How can I configure it?

Normal CPAN configuration tries to install packages into `/usr`. After adding `'makepl_arg' => q[PREFIX=~/cpan_local]`, simple packages seem to build, but I cannot build a package that pulls its dependencies - the dependency is not found.

After I changed it to `'makepl_arg' => q[PREFIX=~/cpan_local LIB=~/cpan_local]`, I get the following message: `Warning: Prerequisite 'ExtUtils::CBuilder => 0.27' for 'D/DA/DAGOLDEN/Module-Build-0.3607.tar.gz' already installed but installation looks suspicious. Skipping another installation attempt, to prevent looping endlessly.`

How can I configure this properly? I want everything that's built to do to `~/cpan_local` automatically. (or for people familiar with python, I'd like this to work like `virtual-env` and running `easy_install` from it).

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory) -- the trick is to use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib) which is very well documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better, install [App::cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus) first. Then just use it to install modules as a regular user. If this user can't write to the `/usr/local/lib/perl*` directories it will resort to writing in its home directory, or you pass it the `-l` or `--local-lib` option to directly install it in your home directory without it figuring out if it can install them system wide.

Finally, installing [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/dist/local-lib) and setting up your environment automatically with your `.bashrc` file will allow you to omit the `--local-lib` option and install to your home directory directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib). The bootstrap instructions should do the trick for you.