# company Perl missing Makefile.PL or Build.PL

Tags: perl, module

WE have perl at work, but I do nt have install permissions on the machines. So i would like to dowload tar files of modules that I want, and build them in a directory of my choosing. 
However I do not have Makefile.PL or Build.PL. How do I proceed ?

```
$ which Makefile.PL
/usr/bin/which: no Makefile.PL in ()
$ which Build.PL
/usr/bin/which: no Build.PL in ()
```

Comment: Makefile.PL or Build.PL is provided by *the distro*, not by *perl*.

Comment: Look at perlbrew which allows you to install perl and perl modules in your user account, https://perlbrew.pl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The utility `which` (a shell-builtin on my system)

> shows the full path of (shell) commands

So it can query the location of installed programs, like `ls` or `cd`, and it also will show whether a command is, in fact, a shell command.  Try `which echo` for instance.

Files `Makefile.PL` and/or `Build.PL` come with a distribution, not with Perl. They are not programs installed on the system, and even when they are there `which` cannot find them.

Make sure to read the documentation with the distribution, in tne particular instructions for how to install it, but you'll start with `perl Makefile.PL` or `perl Build.PL`. For example, once you found the file `Makefile.PL` in the unpacked distribution, a typical process consists of running

> perl Makefile.PL
>   make
>   make test
>   make install

A quick search reveals [this guide on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=128077).  There is a lot more out there.

The `Build.PL` is generally associated with [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/Module-Build-0.4224/lib/Module/Build.pm), and an installation outline is the same as above except that you use `./Build` instead of `make`. With it you don't need to even have `make`.

This approach  is an alternative to [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html), which uses `Makefile.PL` . Comparing these two major alternatives is tricky and I'd rather not get into that. The `Module::Build` can also generate the file `Makefile.PL`. Both files may be provided so that one can use either method, and this decision itself is a topic of discussions.

As for whether to use `Makefile.PL` or `Build.PL` for your install, I suggest to find discussions of the module, starting with its own docs, and see which one people recommend for that distribution. Most often either is fine.

Another related common type of file is `Makefile` (no extension).  This is run by the program `make`, and often without arguments (`make` finds the  `Makefile`). The first command above writes one such file out, and then the remaining `make` commands use it to trigger actions that build (+test+install) the module.

Have you considered using [cpan](https://perldoc.perl.org/cpan.html) or [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Menlo-1.9005/script/cpanm-menlo) instead?  You *can* use them to install stuff as a user into a directory of your choosing.  See, for instance, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735836/how-can-i-install-perl-modules-without-root-privileges) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072101/installing-perl-cpan-modules-in-local-directory).

Or, consider [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.80/lib/App/perlbrew.pm) for a fully contained Perl with all chosen modules, insulated from any future management of the system perl.

Comment: @capser Added a comment on what I forgot to mention in the end -- you can install modules as a user into any directory using cpan/cpanm, and it's really simple. On the other hand, consider having a whole Perl of your liking installed using perlbrew. Then you can have all the modules you want with that Perl.  That way you're protected from changes to system's perl.