# Installing packages with cpan

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, aws-lambda, cpan

I am trying to install these packages in a local directory to use with AWS Lambda.

```
cpan Crypt::CBC . 
cpan Crypt:OPENSSL::AES .
cpan Crypt:Rijndael packages .
```

I don't think they are being installed correctly. How do I make sure they are installed in the local directory

Comment: See [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PERL CPAN modules in local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072101/installing-perl-cpan-modules-in-local-directory)

Comment: Aavoid headaches now and later by installing a local `perl` (e.g. using `perlbrew`) then using `cpan Foo::Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

With [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm):

```
cpanm -l local Crypt::CBC
```

Then in your script:

```
use lib '/path/to/local/lib/perl5';
```

[lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative) could be used with a relative path instead of absolute.

Or when running your script:

```
$ perl -I/path/to/local/lib/perl5 script.pl
```

Comment: For `cpan Crypt:OPENSSL::AES` and `cpan Crypt:Rijndael packages`, I am getting `Couldn't find module errors.`

Comment: @Aaron You misspelled the module names. The first one is spelled `Crypt::OpenSSL::AES` (note it is also case sensitive) and you missed half of the double-colon in the second one.