# Manual installation of a Perl Module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have downloaded the module `Digest::SHA1` and extracted it to a directory (../Digest-SHA1-2.13/) , then copied all the SHA1.* files into (../Digest-SHA1-2.13/Digest)

and in the perl script, I did : use Digest::SHA1;
launching the script like this:

```
perl -I ../Digest-SHA1-2.13/Digest perlscriptname.pl
```

I get this error:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Digest::SHA1 in @INC
```

I assume it has something to do with a shared library (*.so)?, I have no idea how to continue from here.

I can install it directly using CPAN (-MCPAN) module, as I dont have permissions on that server to do that, and can install only locally (where the application is running).
My final goal is to use `Algorithm::CouponCode` which is dependent on `Digest::SHA1`

The weird part is, that I have `Digest::SHA1` installed (`perl -MDigest::SHA1 -e 'print $Digest::SHA1::VERSION'` shows version 2.11), still `Algorithm::CouponCode` (which is installed the same way I did with `Digest::SHA1`) complains it can find it in `@INC`

thanks!

Comment: From the [Stack Overflow Perl FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl?sort=faq): [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use this recipe for manually installing perl modules:

```
tar zxf Digest-SHA1-2.13.tar.gz
cd Digest-SHA1-2.13
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

Note that some distributions will have a `Build.PL` file instead of `Makefile.PL`. In that case use this recipe:

```
tar zxf ...
cd ...
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

(You may be able to get by with just running `make install` and `./Build install`.)

If you need to alter the installation dir then use:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=...
```

or

```
perl Build.PL --install_base ...
```

depending on the kind of module.

For more info see the perldoc for [ExtUtils::MakeMaker::FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker/FAQ.pod) and [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Module-Build-0.3800/lib/Module/Build.pm)

Answer (score 5):

There are two kinds of Perl module: pure-Perl and XS.  Pure-Perl modules are written entirely in Perl, and can usually be installed just by copying the `.pm` files to an appropriate directory.  XS modules are written in both Perl and C (XS is processed into C code by the [ExtUtils::ParseXS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aParseXS) module) and require a C compiler to install them.

As dsolimano said, the easiest way to install Perl modules for the system Perl when you don't have root access is to use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib).  (You could do the same things that `local::lib` does yourself, but why bother?)

The reason why `Digest::SHA1` works by itself but not when you're using `Algorithm::CouponCode` is that the system Perl already has version 2.11 of `Digest::SHA1` installed.  When you use `-I ../Digest-SHA1-2.13/Digest`, then `use Digest::SHA1` picks up the Perl code from ../Digest-SHA1-2.13/Digest, but the shared library that would be built from the XS code is not in the corresponding location.

Comment: local::lib seems to be broken... it tries to fetch modules from non working URLs.. hence I cant install anything

Comment: @soulSurfer2010, you should ask another question about that (with more details).  It sounds too complicated to discuss in comments.

Comment: Ok I will gather all the issues and post a new question. for the meantime, the answer I accepted solved the issue, but now I rather try to dig into why local::lib didnt work, it seems like a really handy module

Answer (score 4):

Any reason why you can't use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib)?

> create and use a local lib/ for perl modules with PERL5LIB

It is basically a tool to help you use a private (non-systemwide) directory as your Perl library directory.

After setting it up, you could run a command like

```
perl -MCPAN -Mlocal::lib -e 'CPAN::install(Algorithm::CouponCode)'
```

and then your script would use your locally installed copy of `Algorithm::CouponCode)`.