# How do I compile a Perl module on Windows with Strawberry?

Tags: windows, perl, compilation, perl-module, strawberry-perl

This is more an open discussion and a conclusion than a real question, hoping it can help someone sometime.

I was looking on how to make Perl module on an Internet disconnected server (otherwise the answer is quite simple: use `cpan`), so the only option I have is to manually compile the modules downloaded from the Internet (CPAN or others) directly on the server.

The problem was that, on a standard Windows server, there is no compiler. So how do I make the modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in your Strawberry Perl installation folder you will see a number of useful utilities, including the compilers `cpp.exe`, `c++.exe`, `gcc.exe` and make utilities `gmake.exe` and `dmake.exe`.

`dmake` and `gcc` together support the use of `cpan` on your installation, and `cpanm` is available as well.

For information on the general process of installing a module, take a look at [`perlmodinstall`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html)

Comment: Perfect generic answer which cover all types of Perl installations.
Nonetheless I think that the better answer should be centered on Strawberry installation case.

Comment: @gyzpunk: I'm not clear what else you want to know. Strawberry Perl has been built and distributed so that the standard method of using `cpan` to install modules works fine in the vast majority of cases. This (or `cpanm`, which is also available) is the recommended method. You say "The problem was that, on a standard Windows server, there is no compiler" and I have solved that by telling you that the the necessary compiler *is* available under Strawberry Perl, and you can build modules in isolation using the standard procedure.

Comment: Yes, you're entirelly right and, as I said, you perfectly answered to my question. My only concern was to give a sort of guide to a completely new user of Strawberry.

Comment: Strawberry perl has deprecated dmake.exe. Use gmake.exe instead. See https://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.26.0.1-64bit.html

Answer (score 3):

Strawberry Perl includes the necessary compiler environment in the default installation, so compiling modules is no problem.

As for installing modules in an offline environment, I am highly partial to [using `cpanmini`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/CPAN-Mini-1.111011/bin/minicpan).  Basically, you create a minimal mirror of all of CPAN using a machine with internet access, then throw that onto your offline machine. Change the `cpan` program's settings to point to this local mirror.  Now you can install nearly any module just like normal with `cpan`.

It may seem like overkill, but it is really very simple.  The CPAN mirror takes up only about 2GB of space, which is nothing these days. You can put it on a USB stick, DVD, or whatever.  And it is a once-for-all solution--the next time you want to install a module, it is already there.

Answer (score 2):

Guys behind Strawberry were smart by packaging among with Perl binaries all you'll need under the `<Strawberry install dir>\c\bin` directory.

Then, to compile a Perl module offline directly on a Windows server, the process is quite simple :

1. Download the module `.tar.gz` file
2. Uncompress it
3. Open a `cmd` in the module directory
4. Type `perl Makefile.PL`
5. Type `dmake`, look if there is no error
6. Type `dmake test`, look if there is no error
7. Type `dmake install`, look if there is no error

And you should be ok !

Don't hesitate to complete this article or to ask your questions in order to improve it.

Comment: For anyone visiting this in the far distant future and who may also be a newbie, some distributions don't have a Makefile.PL files, and instead have a  Build.PL file. this is highlighted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542396/13303690 and may be helpful to some.