# --force command in perl will install modules for sure?

Tags: perl, module, installation

I tried installing [Math::TrulyRandom][1] a random (versus pseudo random) number generator, and on cpan.org, there is only the source code available. My first attempt of installing it was a failure, and then told me to use the --force so that it will be installed the second time. My second time is a failure as well. Can someone explain if I used the --force command correctly, or if there is another way to install Math::TrulyRandom? Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm Math::TrulyRandom
--> Working on Math::TrulyRandom
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GARY/Math-TrulyRandom-1.0.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... OK
Building and testing Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... FAIL
! Installing Math::TrulyRandom failed. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476406246.12316\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.

C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm --force Math::TrulyRandom
--> Working on Math::TrulyRandom
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GARY/Math-TrulyRandom-1.0.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... OK
Building and testing Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... FAIL
! Installing Math::TrulyRandom failed. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476406259.5096\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

I also tried this, but I do not understand what this means (eg. the second to last line of code):

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476412047.4284\Math-TrulyRandom-1.0>exit
Building Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 failed.
You can s)kip, r)etry, e)xamine build log, or l)ook ? [s] e
FAIL
! You don't seem to have a PAGER :/
Building Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 failed.
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm Math::TrulyRandom
--> Working on Math::TrulyRandom
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GARY/Math-TrulyRandom-1.0.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... OK
Building and testing Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... FAIL
! Installing Math::TrulyRandom failed. See C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476549822.10400\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.

C:\Users\Jlinne\Documents>                    cpanm --prompt Math::TrulyRandom
--> Working on Math::TrulyRandom
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GARY/Math-TrulyRandom-1.0.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... OK
Building and testing Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 ... Building Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 failed.
You can s)kip, r)etry, e)xamine build log, or l)ook ? [s] l
Entering C:/Users/Jlinne/.cpanm/work/1476549847.11132/Math-TrulyRandom-1.0 with C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476549847.11132\Math-TrulyRandom-1.0>perl Makefile.PL
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Math::TrulyRandom
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476549847.11132\Math-TrulyRandom-1.0>nmake
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Jlinne\.cpanm\work\1476549847.11132\Math-TrulyRandom-1.0>
```

Answer (score 2):

It likely failed in the building phase and not the testing phase.  The `--force` option just allows `cpanm` to ignore the results of tests.  You should also almost never use `--force`.  Use `--prompt` instead, and then choose the `look` option when prompted.  Once it drops you in the build directory, run `perl Build.pl` or `perl Makefile.PL` (whichever the module uses).  Look for and, if you can, fix them.  If you can't fix them, ask about them on SO.  If it creates a makefile, then run `nmake`. Look for errors, etc.  Then run `nmake test`. Look for errors, etc.  Once all of that works, exit the shell and you will be returned to the prompt.  Chose `retry` and it should install.

You could also just look at the build log and see what went wrong: C:\Users\Jlinne.cpanm\work\1476406259.5096\build.log

I also just noticed you are using MS Windows, are you sure you have a valid build environment (ie nmake is installed, you have a C compiler, etc)?

Comment: I am assuming you know a lot about perl modules and installation. Thanks if you could help me out I added something to the post when inspecting the build log.

Comment: @J.Linne Building on MS Windows can be a pain.  What distribution of Perl are you using (ActiveState, Strawberry, etc)?

Comment: It is strawberry. I don't know where to get nmake. I  keep getting this error when I try to rum nmake and nmaketest.

Comment: Try running `set PAGER=more` in the `cmd` shell before you run `cpanm`.

Comment: I would suspect something is wrong with the building process but I don't know what. I have this problem for a few other modules as well. I added the output when I tried to create a .makefile

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957069/how-do-i-compile-a-perl-module-on-windows-with-strawberry It looks like you need to use `dmake`, the error message even mentions: `Generating a dmake-style Makefile`.  I think `nmake` is used with ActiveState.  Sorry I can't be more help, but I don't have a MS Windows machine to test with.