# Install Zlib and Gzip modules for old version perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to get the perl Gzip module installed for a 5.8.1 version, can't find a rpm around so I did a manual install by copying over the files of a 5.10 install.
I've read through the suggestions in [Manual installation of a Perl Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541019/manual-installation-of-a-perl-module) but it fails to work because of an `undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr` error in zlib.so (I googled a bit and it seems to be caused by perl version mismatch). 
So I'm wondering if there's a place I can find a legitimate copy (this is going into our toolchain repo so it has to be from a reliable source) of the ancient zlib+gzip module? Thanks.

Comment: There is no module called `Gzip`. Which one are you talking about, exactly?

Comment: the stuff in package perl-IO-Compress-Zlib, perl-IO-Compress-Base and perl-IO-Compress-RAW-Zlib (I think these are what they called). Basically it's IO/Compress/Gzip.pm that I need

Comment: Not the best idea mixing the system's packaged installations with your own ones. Check for the perlbrew (http://perlbrew.pl) how to install your own perl and own modules.

Comment: Copying files from one installation to another is **the worst way** to install the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CP5.8.1AN](http://cp5.8.1an.barnyard.co.uk/) index, [IO-Compress-2.061](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.061/) installs fine on your ancient Perl. Build your own package from it, if desired.

Comment: right, turned out I missed a few files to copy over, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

IO-Compress on CPAN probably has what you are looking for:

[IO::Compress](http://metacpan.org/pod/IO%3a%3aCompress)