# Manually installing a Perl module using cygwin GNU make

Tags: perl, makefile, module, cygwin

I am trying to install a few Perl modules, one of them being Time::Format. My corporate group policy does not allow me to use CPAN (since it uses FTP) to install modules. Tried using makefile.pl, but nmake.exe (I am using windows cygwin) seems to be missing too. The policy does not allow to download the nmake.exe executable too. PPM isn't available too.

How do I go about installing module manually? Is there a way where I could manually copy files from this module on to individual folders in my Perl directory? If yes, which files, go where?

Comment: have you tried installing (or checking whether you have) gnu make on your cygwin installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manual installation of a Perl Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541019/manual-installation-of-a-perl-module)

Comment: @JindraHelcl - I seem to have gnu make on my cygwin. Simply searching for the keyword 'make' in my cygwin directory gives me the below list. Please suggest how do I go about installing the module using cygwin GNU make.

Comment: `C:\CYGWIN>dir /s | find "make"
04/27/2007  05:15 PM           191,488 makeinfo.exe
04/06/2007  02:13 PM            13,405 makewhatis
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,899 makewhatis.8.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,917 makewhatis.8.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,708 makewhatis.8.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,998 makewhatis.8.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,786 makewhatis.8.gz
04/27/2007  05:15 PM             2,148 makeinfo.1.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,626 makewhatis.8.gz
04/06/2007  02:13 PM             1,591 makewhatis.8.gz`

Comment: I think the list shows that you don't have make.. Just try to run 'make' from your cygwin console.

Comment: When you have the make utility, you usually can run these commands: `perl Makefile.pl`, `make`, `make test`, and `make install`

Comment: CPAN for a long while now has supported HTTP as well as FTP. If it's specifically the FTP part your company objects to (not entirely unreasonably), you might get better luck using some HTTP mirrors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get around the FTP restriction by using a [minicpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan). Basically this lets you build your own local CPAN mirror, for example on a USB key drive. It's intended to carry a snapshot of CPAN with you, e.g. when you are in transatlantic flights and just really need that module you didn't install.

However, those restrictions are probably there for a reason. Downloading and installing/copying stuff from the internet might be against the corporate policy just the same as it's an external source. You should check that. On the other hand, those policies are often intended for the average office user that is not a developer, so you might be able to talk to them and explain why you and your team should be excepted from this policy, and how reusing code from CPAN would save your company a lot of time, which equals money.